# Give examples of functions which demonstrate covariance and contravariance in the cases of both overloading and overriding in Java?

Tags: java, covariance, contravariance

Please show a good example for covariance and contravariance in Java.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

**Covariance:**

```
class Super {
  Object getSomething(){}
}
class Sub extends Super {
  String getSomething() {}
}
```

Sub#getSomething is covariant because it returns a subclass of the return type of Super#getSomething (but fullfills the contract of Super.getSomething())

**Contravariance**

```
class Super{
  void doSomething(String parameter)
}
class Sub extends Super{
  void doSomething(Object parameter)
}
```

Sub#doSomething is contravariant because it takes a parameter of a superclass of the parameter of Super#doSomething (but, again, fullfills the contract of Super#doSomething)

*Notice: this example doesn't work in Java. The Java compiler would overload and not override the doSomething()-Method. Other languages do support this style of contravariance.*

**Generics**

This is also possible for Generics:

```
List<String> aList...
List<? extends Object> covariantList = aList;
List<? super String> contravariantList = aList;
```

You can now access all methods of `covariantList` that doesn't take a generic parameter (as it *must* be something "extends Object"), but getters will work fine (as the returned object will always be of type "Object")

The opposite is true for `contravariantList`: You can access all methods with generic parameters (you know it must be a superclass of "String", so you can always pass one), but no getters (The returned type may be of any other supertype of String)

Comment: The first example of contravariance doesn't work in Java. doSomething() in the Sub class is an overload, not an override.

Comment: Indeed. Java does not support contravariant arguments in subtyping. Only covariance for what concern method return types (like in the first example).

Comment: Great answer. Covariance looks logical to me. But could you point me a paragraph in JLS which describes contravariance? Why Sub.doSomething is invoked?

Comment: As Craig pointed out, it isn't. I think here is a clash between overriding and overloading and SUN did choose (as always) the backward-compatible option. So in Java you can't use contravariant parameters when overriding a method.

Answer (score 50):

**Co-variance: Iterable and Iterator.** It almost always makes sense to define a co-variant `Iterable` or `Iterator`. `Iterator<? extends T>` can be used just as `Iterator<T>` - the only place where the type parameter appears is the return type from the `next` method, so it can be safely up-cast to `T`. But if you have `S` extends `T`, you can also assign `Iterator<S>` to a variable of type `Iterator<? extends T>`. For example if you are defining a find method:

```
boolean find(Iterable<Object> where, Object what)
```

you won't be able to call it with `List<Integer>` and `5`, so it's better defined as

```
boolean find(Iterable<?> where, Object what)
```

**Contra-variance: Comparator.** It almost always makes sense to use `Comparator<? super T>`, because it can be used just as `Comparator<T>`. The type parameter appears only as the `compare` method parameter type, so `T` can be safely passed to it. For example if you have a `DateComparator implements Comparator<java.util.Date> { ... }` and you want to sort a `List<java.sql.Date>` with that comparator (`java.sql.Date` is a sub-class of `java.util.Date`), you can do with:

```
<T> void sort(List<T> what, Comparator<? super T> how)
```

but not with

```
<T> void sort(List<T> what, Comparator<T> how)
```

Answer (score -7):

Look at the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In effect, if class B extends class A then you should be able to use a B whenever an A is required.

Comment: This isn't answering the question and is misleading. It would be entirely possible to design a variant system that breaks semantic correctness and therefore violates LSP.

Comment: this isn't the case for `contra variant` say. `super.doSomething("String")` could not be replaced by  `sub.doSomething(Object)`.

Comment: It is not the question