# Why can't add element in a upper bound generics List?

Tags: java, generics

I have a list with upper bound generics.

```
 List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<>();
 l.add(new Integer(3));  //ERROR
 l.add(new Double(3.3)); // ERROR
```

I don't understand the problem, because Integer and Double extend Number.

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: @Mason It must be Java 7+ because of the `<>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java generic and wild card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344330/java-generic-and-wild-card)

Comment: @Radiodef Never know could have had an error with his initialization of the List.

Comment: Just make it `List<Number>` instead of the generic wildcard. You can't know how the type will get filled in so it will throw an error.

Comment: @Mason That said, I am actually not sure why this would compile because `<>` implies type inference. You cannot do `new ArrayList<? extends Number>` so I don't know why the `<>` would be allowed. I am not sure what Java 7 would infer in that case.

Comment: @Radiodef good point, I need to test.

Answer (score 43):

`List<? extends Number>` does not mean "a list that can hold all objects of subclasses of `Number`", it means "a list parameterized to one concrete class that extends `Number`". It's not the contents of the list itself you are defining, it's what the parameterized type of the actual list-object assigned to the variable can be (boy, this is harder to explain than it is to understand :) )

So, you can do:

```
List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

If you want a list that is able to hold any object of class Number or its subclasses, just do this:

```
List<Number> l = new ArrayList<>();

l.add(new Integer(33));
l.add(new Double(33.3d));
```

(The boxing of the values inserted is unnecessary, but there for clarity..)

Comment: Crucially, the wildcard means that the List *once had a type* but *we don't know what it is anymore*.

Comment: "boy, this is harder to explain than it is to understand :)" That's true of most things, I think.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist true, you have to read it a couple of times, but it is correctly written..

Answer (score 9):

Upper bounded and unbounded wildcard collections are immutable.

For example, you cannot do:

```
List<? extends Number> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(new Integer(3)); //will not compile
```

This fails to compile because java does not know what type of List `List<? extends Number>` is at compilation time.

So the example above, at compile time,  `myList` could be `List<Double>`or `List<Integer>` or a `List` of any subclass of `Number`. And since you cannot add a `Double` to a `List<Integer>` or vise-versa, the compilation fails.

Comment: Ok so could you give me an example of a list instantiation using "upper bound" and adding elements to it. I don't think it's possible! When creating a list you can only use "lower bound" since it's never going to be immutable. "Upper bound" can still be used with a Collection in a method parameter. Could you confirm this.

Comment: "Upper bounded and unbounded wildcard collections are immutable" - not exactly, they can still have elements removed and can also be cleared :-)

Comment: element of which type ??

Comment: Your explanation is simple and understandable.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with upper-bounded generics is that the compiler doesn't know the exact type that is going to be used, for example:

```
List<? extends Number> upperBounded = new ArrayList<Integer>();
upperBounded = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

`upperBounded` can be a List of Integers as well as a list of Doubles or any other descendant of Number. Now imagine what will happen if Java allowed us to add any subclass of Number to that List.

```
List<? extends Number> upperBounded = new ArrayList<Integer>();
upperBounded.add(1.0); // compile-time error
```

Good thing that Java prevents us from doing that because this would introduce a lot of bugs.

The same applies to the unbounded generic types.

Now what about the lower-bounded generics?

```
List<? super Integer> lowerBounded = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lowerBounded.add(0);
```

This is is perfectly fine because we are safe to assume that we can add Integers to any List of an Integer superclass and this will not lead to inconsistency, for example:

```
List<? super Integer> lowerBounded = new ArrayList<Number>();
lowerBounded.add(0);
```

Here we have a reference that allows a List of Integers or one of the Integer supertypes. ArrayList of Numbers fits into that definition, so we are able to assign it to that reference. Then we can add an Integer to this list, and this is also fine because a List of Numbers can contain an Integer (because Integer is a Number).

It may be surprising, but you can't add anything not assignable to Integer to this list for the same reason as I explained above for lower-bounded generics.

```
List<? super Integer> lowerBounded = new ArrayList<Number>();
lowerBounded.add(1.0); // compile-time error
```

As the compiler does not know the List of which exact type will be used, it does not allow us to add anything that could potentially break the promise given by generics.

Hope that helps.

Comment: why can't the compiler just add the value as Number to the list for the upperbounded wildcard, it should be fine? just like we can read from upper bounded list item as Number

Comment: @HKIT then we would still have this problem:
<pre><code>List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>
List<? extends Number> numbers = integers;
// now 'numbers' and 'integers' refer to the same list
numbers.add(1.0); // 1.0 extends Number but not Integer, adding this to 'integers' would be an error
for (Integer integer : integers) {
    // and we would have problems with casting
    System.out.println(integer);
}
</code></pre>

Answer (score 2):

Because `List<? extends Number>` means that your variable `l` holds a value of type `List` with **concrete** (but unknown!) type argument that extends `Number`.

You can add only `null`, because `l` can hold a `List<MyClass>` for example, where `MyClass` is your class that extends `Number`, but nor `Integer`, nor `Double` value can be casted to `MyClass`.

Comment: why can't we add Number type, all elements inside are Number, just like we can get list item as number.

Comment: because for example in a cell with type `Lost<? extends Number>` can be `List<Integer>` and you can't add `Number` in case it's 3.14

Answer (score 1):

I will add one more way to add the subtypes of `Number` to this list. i.e

```
List<? super Number> l = new ArrayList<>();
 l.add(new Integer(3));  //OK
 l.add(new Double(3.3)); //OK
```

This is allowed since the list is parameterized to be any *unknown supertype* of `Number` class. so, compiler allows the known subtype of `Number`. i.e `Integer` and `Double` types

Answer (score 0):

Yes in case of

```
List<? extends Number>
```

this is just a reference, may be the actual object will be

```
List<Integer>
```

so you should not be allowed to add new Double(5.0) in a list of Integer.