# wild cards in collections: extends, super

Tags: java, java-collections-api

I encounter the problem of using wild cards in collections. It is similar to the question in [java generic and wild card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344330/java-generic-and-wild-card) but the responses there I found confuse. Could please advise?

**Problem**: I would like to use a collection with a class and its subtypes. On basis of the docs, I expected I have to use the `<? extends myclass>` but it does not work with that, however without using it, it works smoothly. Why is it this way, it should exactly be **opposit**? Is it the same with the `<? super myclass>` for super classes?

The **correct** example:

```
    List<Number> nl = new ArrayList<>();
    nl.add(new Integer(2));
    System.out.println("===> List<Number>.add (new Integer(2)) = " + nl.get(0));
```

The **incorrect** example:

```
List<? extends Number> nl = new ArrayList<>();
nl.add(new Integer(2));
System.out.println("===> List<Number>.add (new Integer(2)) = " + nl.get(0));
```

I would appreciate your advice. Thanks a lot, Tamas