# How can an interface include a method that references the concrete implementation type of the interface in its signature or return type?

Tags: java, generics, interface, return-type, method-signature

Suppose I am designing something like the following interface:

```
public interface MyInterface{
  public MyInterface method1();
  public void method2(MyInterface mi);
}
```

However, there is the caveat that the return type for `method1` and the parameter for `method2` match the concrete implementation and not just `MyInterface`.  That is, if I have `MyInterfaceImpl` that implements `MyInterface`, it needs to have the following:

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface{
  @Override
  public MyInterfaceImpl method1(){...}

  @Override
  public void method2(MyInterfaceImpl mi){...}
}
```

As written above, `method1` won't cause any compile errors, but there is nothing guaranteeing that the return type matches in all implementations.  Of course `method2` won't even compile because the signature does not match the interface.

One candidate solution is to use self-referential or recursive bounds in generics:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends MyInterface<T>>{
  public T method1();
  public void method2(T mi);
}

public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface<MyInterfaceImpl>{
  @Override
  public MyInterfaceImpl method1();

  @Override
  public void method2(MyInterfaceImpl mi);
}
```

This would get me what I want with one exception: other implementations might pass the wrong generic type (nothing forces `T` to match the concrete type).  So potentially someone else could implement the following:

```
public class NotMyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface<MyInterfaceImpl>{
  @Override
  public MyInterfaceImpl method1();

  @Override
  public void method2(MyInterfaceImpl mi);
}
```

That would compile just fine even though `NotMyInterfaceImpl` *should* implement `MyInterface<NotMyInterfaceImpl>`.*  That makes me think I need something else.

*Note that I don't think I'm trying to violate LSP; I'm OK with the return type/parameter being subclasses of `NotMyInterfaceImpl`.

So I don't know of a clean way to do this.  That leads me to believe that I might be focusing too much on implementation details in the interface, but it doesn't seem that way to me.  Is there any way to do the type of thing I described, or is this some kind of smell that I'm putting something in an interface that doesn't belong there?

Comment: I don't want to be rude when I say this, but *typically* trying to make an interface required to know what it's underlying implementation is shows a fundamental lack of understanding of the purpose of an interface. You may need to take a step back from your design.

Comment: Well if you read my last paragraph, I am a bit concerned that I *might* be violating what I should be doing with an interface.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the exact situation faced by the `Comparable` interface (its `compareTo` method wants to take an argument the same type as the object it is called on). So what does it do? It's simply defined as `Comparable<T>`. The idea is that an implementing class "should" implement `Comparable` with itself as the parameter (allowing it to "compare to" itself); but this is not enforced (since there is no way to do it).

Yes, as you noted, this will allow any class to implement `Comparable` with a parameter of any other class: `class Foo implements Comparable<Bar>` where `Foo` and `Bar` have no relation to each other. However, this is not really a problem.

All the methods and classes (sorting, maximum, etc.) that require `Comparable` objects have the following generic type constraint `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`. This ensures that objects of type T are comparable with themselves. That way, it is completely type-safe. So the enforcement is not made in the declaration of the Comparable interface, but in the places that use it.

(I notice that you use `<T extends MyInterface<T>>` while `Comparable` uses simply `<T>`. Although `<T extends MyInterface<T>>` will exclude cases where the type parameter does not implement `MyInterface`, it will not exclude cases where the type parameter does implement `MyInterface`, but is different than the class. So what's the point of half-excluding some cases? If you adopt `Comparable`'s way of restricting it where they are used, it's type-safe anyway, so there is no point in adding more restrictions.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this cannot be done. There is simply no way to refer to an object's implementation class in the framework of generics, nor, as far as i know, any way to construct a cage out of pure generics which is capable of constraining the implementation class to match a type parameter.

The most useful thing i can suggest is using a self-referential parameter, and then always acquiring instances of implementations from factory methods which look like:

```
public <T extends MyInterface<T>> T newInstance();
```

It is easier for a camel to pass through the eye of a needle than for an instance of `NotMyInterfaceImpl` to pass through that return type. So, although troublemakers could write classes which do not conform to your masterplan, they couldn't return them from factories. Unless `NotMyInterfaceImpl` extended `MyInterfaceImpl`; but then, in a sense, it would also be a `MyInterfaceImpl`, so perhaps that would be kosher?

EDIT: A slightly more useful version of that idea is to always pass instances of implementations of the interface around in a suitably restrictive holder, like:

```
class Holder<T extends MyInterface<T>> {
    public final T value;
}
```

If someone gives you a `Holder<Q>`, then you know that `Q` must be a version of `MyInterface` bound to itself, which is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not legal because you are trying to narrow the parameter of the implemented type, and this *"does not make sense"*. You are tryint to use **"covariant" parameters**, and only covariant return types are allowed (and even logic, and only [supported from Java 5](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/covariant-parameter-types-2.html)).

I mean, if it was possible to use covariant parameter types, you could do things like:

```
MyInterface instance = new MyInterfaceImpl();
```

And then, invoke on "instance" the method with another implementation supported by the interface but not supported by the MyInterfaceImpl class this way:

```
instance.method2(new MyInterfaceImpl_2());
```

Java cannot convert `MyInterfaceImpl_2` to `MyInterfaceImpl`, so it prevents you from doing so at compilation time.

What you could do is to widen the parameter, using **"contravariant"** parameter, which would be logic. For more detail on this, check this anser:

[Demonstrate covariance and contravariance in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java)

The only workaround that I can think of, is to solve the problem at runtime, I mean, doing something like this:

```
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface{
  @Override
  public void method2(MyInterface mi){
        realMethod((MyInterfaceImpl) mi);
  }
  public void realMethod(MyInterfaceImpl) {...}
}
```

But you could get ClassCast exception, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The point of returning the interface is such that the method does not care the actual implementation of the returned object. In your case you actually *want* to mandate the type to be a particular sub-implementation of that interface.

To apply the constraints that you described above, IMHO the design should probably be a base class instead of an interface. This allows you to control the implementation, for example a top-level flow, and leave low-level strategy to sub-classes to implement:

```
class MyBaseImpl {
    public final void fixedFlow() {
        MyBaseImpl obj = method1();
        obj.method2(this);
    }
    protected abstract MyBaseImpl method1();
    ....
}
```

There has to be other methods to make it interesting...; perhaps you have good reasons to want to do this...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public interface MyInterface {

    static abstract class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {

        @Override
        public abstract MyInterfaceImpl method1();

        @Override
        public abstract void method2(MyInterfaceImpl mi);

    }    

    MyInterfaceImpl method1();
    void method2(MyInterfaceImpl mi);

}
```

And you could even implement method 1 or 2 instead of making them abstract.