# self-referential methods with generic return type for multiple inherited classes

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, self-reference

It's probably a bit difficult to describe. However, I'll try it ;)

Following the fluent style, it is common that a method of a class returns the class instance itself (this).

```
public class A {

    public A doSomething() {

        // do something here

        return this;
    }

}
```

When extending such a fluent style class one could do this rather easy in the first inheritance step via a generic type and casting the return type to this generic type in the super class.

```
public class A<T extends A<T>> {

    public T doSomething() {

        // do something here

        return (T) this;
    }

}

public class B extends A<B> {

    // an extended class of class A

}
```

However, when doing another inheritance step on this extended class, I'm running into trouble when trying to define the generic return type of the methods (in the upper classes) and the class description itself, e.g., a method in the super-super class would not return the type of the extend class but rather then the type of the super-class. However, my intention was that these fluent style methods should always return the type of the current class (and not is upper classes).

So is it possible to define a solution by utilising generics?

PS: I know, a simple workaround might be override all these method in the extended class and cast them to the current type. However, I'm interested in a more elegant solution ;)

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7604030/387852

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try:

```
class A<T> { }

class B<T extends A<? super T>> extends A<T> { }

class C extends B<C> { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
public class TestFluent<T extends TestFluent<?>> {

    public T get() {
        return (T) this;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        TestFluent2<TestFluent2<?>> f2 = new TestFluent2<TestFluent2<?>>();
        TestFluent2<?> result2 = f2.get();

        TestFluent3<TestFluent3<?>> t3 = new TestFluent3<TestFluent3<?>>();
        TestFluent3<?> result3 = t3.get();

        System.out.println(result2);
        System.out.println(result3);
    }
}

class TestFluent2<T extends TestFluent2<?>> extends TestFluent<T> {
}

class TestFluent3<T extends TestFluent3<?>> extends TestFluent2<T> {
}
```

This will return:

```
TestFluent2@7919298d
TestFluent3@62f72617
```

Comment: yeah, this looks a bit promising. I also tried it with wildcards before, but I didn't find a applicable solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to "return the type of the current class" in general.

Even the code you posted above is unsafe: `public class C extends A<B>` is legal, but calling `doSomething()` on it, expecting a `B`, will crash.

Comment: ... because it is public class B extends A<B> and not public class C extends A<B> ;)

Comment: I am saying that defining `public class C extends A<B>` is legal after you define `public class B extends A<B>`, is it not?

Comment: ... of course, it's legal. However, it didn't cause the expected behaviour, or? (... anyway ...)

Comment: and then when you do `C foo = ...; B bar = foo.doSomething();` it will crash. so it is not safe

Comment: again, that's not what I would like to do: I would like to do: B foo = ...; foo.doSomething().doSomethingElse().doSomethingDifferent(). ... so it's always returning B (self-referential). So please don't mix up the described use case with another thing.

Comment: @zazi unfortunately it's not just about the use case, not even what you (as the developer of this code) would do. It's about what **others** would do with your API, and how to prevent illegal usage (and thus prevent errors and faults). Otherwise there are tons of simpler solutions. a note: even you yourself will fall into *others* category after releasing the code!!! people make unintended mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation to implement extensible fluent interfaces.  Pros: no casts.  Cons: verbose.

```
public interface FluentGranddad< C extends FluentGranddad< C > > {
    C appendFoo( Foo foo );
}
public interface FluentDad< C extends FluentDad< C > > extends FluentGranddad< C > {
    C appendBar( Bar b );
}
public interface FluentKid< C extends FluentKid< C > > extends FluentDad< C > {
    C appendSplat( Splat s );
}

public class Babbler implements FluentKid< Babbler > {
    FluentDad< ? > dad;
    public Babbler( FluentDad< ? > dad ) {
        this.dad = dad;
    }

    // delegation methods
    @Override public Babbler appendFoo( Foo foo ) {
        dad.appendFoo( foo );
        return this;
    }
    @Override public Babbler appendBar( Bar bar ) {
        dad.appendBar( bar );
        return this;
    }

    // example instance method
    @Override public Babbler appendSplat( Splat s ) {
        dad.getState().append( s.toString() );
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know this is the simple workaround which I've currently applied. However, it's a bit cumbersome (from my POV) to repeat this always, when introducing a new extension layer.