# Covariance, Invariance and Contravariance explained in plain English?

Tags: java, covariance, contravariance

Today, I read some articles about Covariance, Contravariance (and Invariance) in Java. I read the English and German Wikipedia article, and some other blog posts and articles from IBM.

But I'm still a little bit confused on what these exactly are about? Some say it's about relationship between types and subtypes, some say it's about type conversion and some say it's used to decide whether a method is overridden or overloaded.

So I'm looking for an easy explanation in plain English, that shows a beginner what Covariance and Contravariance (and Invariance) is. Plus point for an easy example.

Comment: Please refer to this post, it may be helpful for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/2501023/218717

Comment: Perhaps better a programmer's stack exchange type question. If you do post there, consider stating just what you do understand, and what specifically confuses you, because right now you're asking someone to re-write a whole tutorial for you.

Answer (score 366, accepted):

> Some say it is about relationship between types and subtypes, other say it is about type conversion and others say it is used to decide whether a method is overwritten or overloaded.

All of the above.

At heart, these terms describe how the subtype relation is affected by type transformations. That is, if `A` and `B` are types, `f` is a type transformation, and ≤ the subtype relation (i.e. `A ≤ B` means that `A` is a subtype of `B`), we have

- `f` is covariant if `A ≤ B` implies that `f(A) ≤ f(B)`
- `f` is contravariant if `A ≤ B` implies that `f(B) ≤ f(A)`
- `f` is invariant if neither of the above holds

Let's consider an example. Let `f(A) = List<A>` where `List` is declared by

```
class List<T> { ... }
```

Is `f` covariant, contravariant, or invariant? Covariant would mean that a `List<String>` is a subtype of `List<Object>`, contravariant that a `List<Object>` is a subtype of `List<String>` and invariant that neither is a subtype of the other, i.e. `List<String>` and `List<Object>` are inconvertible types. In Java, the latter is true, we say (somewhat informally) that *generics* are invariant.

Another example. Let `f(A) = A[]`. Is `f` covariant, contravariant, or invariant? That is, is String[] a subtype of Object[], Object[] a subtype of String[], or is neither a subtype of the other? (Answer: In Java, arrays are covariant)

This was still rather abstract. To make it more concrete, let's look at which operations in Java are defined in terms of the subtype relation. The simplest example is assignment. The statement

```
x = y;
```

will compile only if `typeof(y) ≤ typeof(x)`. That is, we have just learned that the statements

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<String>();
```

will not compile in Java, but

```
Object[] objects = new String[1];
```

will.

Another example where the subtype relation matters is a method invocation expression:

```
result = method(a);
```

Informally speaking, this statement is evaluated by assigning the value of `a` to the method's first parameter, then executing the body of the method, and then assigning the methods return value to `result`. Like the plain assignment in the last example, the "right hand side" must be a subtype of the "left hand side", i.e. this statement can only be valid if `typeof(a) ≤ typeof(parameter(method))` and `returntype(method) ≤ typeof(result)`. That is, if method is declared by:

```
Number[] method(ArrayList<Number> list) { ... }
```

none of the following expressions will compile:

```
Integer[] result = method(new ArrayList<Integer>());
Number[] result = method(new ArrayList<Integer>());
Object[] result = method(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

but

```
Number[] result = method(new ArrayList<Number>());
Object[] result = method(new ArrayList<Number>());
```

will.

Another example where subtyping matters is overriding. Consider:

```
Super sup = new Sub();
Number n = sup.method(1);
```

where

```
class Super {
    Number method(Number n) { ... }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    @Override 
    Number method(Number n);
}
```

Informally, the runtime will rewrite this to:

```
class Super {
    Number method(Number n) {
        if (this instanceof Sub) {
            return ((Sub) this).method(n);  // *
        } else {
            ... 
        }
    }
}
```

For the marked line to compile, the method parameter of the overriding method must be a supertype of the method parameter of the overridden method, and the return type a subtype of the overridden method's one. Formally speaking, `f(A) = parametertype(method asdeclaredin(A))` must at least be contravariant, and if `f(A) = returntype(method asdeclaredin(A))` must at least be covariant.

Note the "at least" above. Those are minimum requirements any reasonable statically type safe object oriented programming language will enforce, but a programming language may elect to be more strict. In the case of Java 1.4, parameter types and method return types must be identical (except for type erasure) when overriding methods, i.e. `parametertype(method asdeclaredin(A)) = parametertype(method asdeclaredin(B))` when overriding. Since Java 1.5, covariant return types are permitted when overriding, i.e. the following will compile in Java 1.5, but not in Java 1.4:

```
class Collection {
    Iterator iterator() { ... }
}

class List extends Collection {
    @Override 
    ListIterator iterator() { ... }
}
```

I hope I covered everything - or rather, scratched the surface. Still I hope it will help to understand the abstract, but important concept of type variance.

Comment: Also, since Java 1.5 contravariant argument types are permitted when overriding. I think you missed that.

Comment: Are they? I just tried it in eclipse, and the compiler thought I meant to overload rather than override, and rejected the code when I placed an @Override annotation on the subclass method. Do you have any evidence for your claim that Java supports contravariant argument types?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I believed someone without checking it myself.

Comment: Great answear +1
BTW assigements in java are treated as expressions, not as statements, so x = y and ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<Object>() are actually expressions

Comment: @meriton so - for plain little old me - contravariance (by your explanation) is simply the ability to assign a less specific type (a parent) to a more specific type, correct? If so - i.e. I understood what you wrote - you should read the terrible job MSDN does to try and explain the same thing in C#. Generics (not collections) are overly opinionated in C#.

Comment: I read a lot of documentation and watched a few talks about this topic but this is by far the best explanation. Thnx a lot.

Comment: +1 for being absolutely leman and simple with `A ≤ B`. That notation makes things much much more simple and meaningful. Good read...

Comment: I know this is a very old answer but please can someone help with the line.       ```the method parameter of the overriding method must be a supertype of the method parameter of the overridden method```. From my Understanding of Java, the method parameters of both the Overridden and Overriding methods must be of the same type

Comment: @Mab: I explain that in the next paragraph (the one with "Note the "at least" above")

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was initially confused since it follows the statement: ```For the marked line to compile```. I think I understand now, from the explanation, the restrictions of Overridden and Overriding method parameter not being Contravariant is specific to Java and other language that chooses to

Comment: Perhaps "invariant" is defined the way you say in the Java world of types, but by construction the word "invariant" means "does not vary" which would imply:
f is invariant if A =  B implies that f(A) = f(B)

Comment: ... which would be a nonsensical interpretation, because "A = B implies that f(A) = f(B)" is a tautology which holds for every function: if you do the same thing to the same number, you get the same result! That's so obvious we don't need a word for it. And so computer scientists everywhere use "invariant" to describe a far more interesting property, namely the absence of covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 34):

Variance is about relationships between classes with different generics parameters. Their relationships are the reason why we can cast them.

Co and Contra variance are pretty logical things. Language type system forces us to support real life logic. It's easy to understand by example.

### Covariance

For instance you want to buy a flower and you have two flowers shop in your city: rose shop and daisy shop.

If you ask someone "where is the flowers shop?" and someone tells you where is rose shop, would it be okay? yes, because rose is a flower, if you want to buy a flower you can buy a rose. The same applies if someone replied you with the address of the daisy shop.
This is example of **covariance**: you are allowed to cast `A<C>` to `A<B>`, where `C` is a subclass of `B`, if `A` produces generic values (returns as a result from the function). Covariance is about producers.

Types:

```
class Flower {  }
class Rose extends Flower { }
class Daisy extends Flower { }

interface FlowerShop<T extends Flower> {
    T getFlower();
}

class RoseShop implements FlowerShop<Rose> {
    @Override
    public Rose getFlower() {
        return new Rose();
    }
}

class DaisyShop implements FlowerShop<Daisy> {
    @Override
    public Daisy getFlower() {
        return new Daisy();
    }
}
```

Question is "where is the flower shop?", answer is "rose shop there":

```
static FlowerShop<? extends Flower> tellMeShopAddress() {
    return new RoseShop();
}
```

### Contravariance

For instance you want to gift flower to your girlfriend. If your girlfriend loves any flower, can you consider her as a person who loves roses, or as a person who loves daisies? yes, because if she loves any flower she would love both rose and daisy.
This is an example of the **contravariance**: you’re allowed to cast `A<B>` to `A<C>`, where `C` is subclass of `B`, if `A` consumes generic value. Contravariance is about consumers.

Types:

```
interface PrettyGirl<TFavouriteFlower extends Flower> {
    void takeGift(TFavouriteFlower flower);
}

class AnyFlowerLover implements PrettyGirl<Flower> {
    @Override
    public void takeGift(Flower flower) {
        System.out.println("I like all flowers!");
    }

}
```

You're considering your girlfriend who loves any flower as someone who loves roses, and giving her a rose:

```
PrettyGirl<? super Rose> girlfriend = new AnyFlowerLover();
girlfriend.takeGift(new Rose());
```

You can find more at the [Source](https://vadzimv.dev/2019/10/01/generic-programming-part-1-introduction.html).

Comment: @Peter, thanks, it's a fair point. Invariance it's when there is no relationships between classes with different generic parameters, i.e. you can't cast A<B> to A<C> whatever relationship between B and C is.

Answer (score 13):

Taking the java type system, and then classes:

*Any object of some type T can be substituted with an object of subtype of T.*

TYPE VARIANCE - CLASS METHODS HAVE THE FOLLOWING CONSEQUENCES

```
class A {
    public S f(U u) { ... }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public T f(V v) { ... }
}

B b = new B();
t = b.f(v);
A a = ...; // Might have type B
s = a.f(u); // and then do V v = u;
```

It can be seen, that:

- The T must be subtype S (**covariant, as B is subtype of A**).
- The V must be supertype of U (**contravariant**, as contra inheritance direction).

Now co- and contra- relate to B being subtype of A. The following stronger typings may be introduced with more specific knowledge. In the subtype.

Covariance (available in Java) is useful, to say that one returns a more specific result in the subtype; especially seen when A=T and B=S.
Contravariance says you are prepared to handle a more general argument.