# Types of objects in Scala's Lists

Tags: list, scala, types

I was under impression that every object in a Scala List must have the same type and if we need to have a collection of something of different types, tuples should be used.

From Scala's [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List), `List` is

> A class for immutable linked lists representing ordered collections of
>   elements of type.

```
scala> val l1 = List(1,2,3)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val l1 = List(1,2,3, "oh really?!")
l1: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, oh really?!)
```

This does not seem to be the case. After all `Any` on its own is a valid `Scala` type and everything can be reduced to it.

Please clarify

Comment: `List[T]` may contain any value whose type is compatible with `T`, not just those that are exactly `T`. When you write a `List` literal such as `List(1, 2, 3, "string")` the compiler finds a supertype that encompasses the types of all the values in the arguments. When you mix types from the `AnyVal` (primitive types) and the `AnyRef` (class types) the only common supertype is `Any`, which is what happened in your 2nd example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't specify the type of the list explicitly and you put in two types of objects, it would seem convenient that it makes this a list of type 'Any' and it doesn't break the rules.
If you had said `val l1: List[Int] = List(1,2,3, "oh really?!")` it would have been a different case (as in: it would tell you there's a type mismatch)

It doesn't always just resolve to Any either.
Consider you have a class called Vehicle and two classes inheriting from it called Bike and Car.

```
val car = new Car
val bike = new Bike
val vehicleList = List(car, bike)
```

vehicleList will now be of type Vehicle. If you had only put a Car or a Bike in there then it would have been of that specific type.

Optional background information: A List in Scala is covariant, meaning that if Int and String are subtypes of Any, then List[Int] and List[String] are also subtypes of List[Any]. This means you can have a list that contains Integers and Strings and is the reason that your statement is valid and automatically results in a List[Any]. This is not always a given fact by the way and can actually lead to trouble if the list is mutable. Luckily the default List in Scala isn't. If you want to know more, a longer explanation can be found at [Covariance, Invariance and Contravariance explained in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english)

Comment: I wouldn't call inferring a least upper bound of `Any` 'convenient'. It usually means you're doing something wrong, which is why there's a warning for it in Scala.

Comment: Maybe so, but the way his question was phrased indicated he didn't expect it to be possible to have different types in the list at all, which is what I was referring to with 'convenient', such as in my example with Vehicles.