# Cast to generic type (T) gives "unchecked cast" warning

Tags: java, list, generics, bounded-types

I got a small problem here regarding generics bounded type with lists. Please help out!

Model.java

```
public class Model {
}
```

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA<T extends Model> {
    private List<T> models;

    public ClassA() {
        models.add((T) new Model());
    }
}
```

It gives me an unchecked cast from Model to T warning on this line:

```
models.add((T) new Model());
```

I understand I'm getting this warning because all I can safely cast from a sub class into a super class but not the other way round.

Is there any way to get over this problem or can I just safely supress the warning?

Comment: The T can be subclass of Model. So you cannot cast Model to its subclass. What do you want to do?

Comment: why not `models.add(new T());`?

Comment: Note that even though you can cast and add it, you will get a `ClassCastException` when you try to use the elements in the list as `T` type objects where `T` is a subclass of `Model`.

Comment: @Cruncher `new T()` won't compile due to type erasure.

Comment: You're trying to do it backwards. It's not safe to ignore that warning. Imagine class B that extends Model. Then declare ClassA<B> (which is valid because B extends Model). Then try doing a case from your new Model to B. That will fail, because while B is a Model, a Model is not B.

Comment: If you want them to just always use Model, then you don't need Generics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do.

Since **T** is a subclass of **Model**:

- every **T** is a **Model**
- but not every **Model** is a **T**.

*Specifically:*

If you construct a new Model by calling **new Model()**, the instance is exactly a Model and not an instance of any subclass.

Where **Subclass extends Superclass**, you can never successfully do this:

```
(Subclass) new Superclass();
```

Because of this, you can not successfully cast a new Model to an instance of T.

The compiler will just give you a warning which you can either ignore or suppress, but you'll get a **ClassCastException** when you run your program and call the **add()** method.

Answer (score 2):

Take this example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA<SubModel> models = new ClassA<>();
    for (SubModel model : models.getModels()){
        model.run(); // runtime ClassCastException
    }
}
public static class ClassA<T extends Model> {
    private List<T> models = new LinkedList<>();

    public ClassA() {
        models.add((T)new Model()); // compiles and warns
    }

    public List<T> getModels() {
        return models;
    }
}
public static class SubModel extends Model {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
public static class Model {
}
```

The object you've added to `models` is of runtime type `Model`, which doesn't have a `run()` method.

When you eventually try to use the object as an object of type `SubModel`, you'll get a `ClassCastException` as I do in the `main()` method.

You really shouldn't do this, ie. add parent type objects to possible suptype type objects.

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize the list before adding elements in your constructor. I think you you might have copied only the relavant code snippet and thats why it was left out.

Also, I think the only way is to suppress warnings. More info only covariance, contravariance here : [Covariance, Invariance and Contravariance explained in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english)

Comment: Suppressing the warning will only delay the inevitable `ClassCastException`. And it's true that the list needs to be `new`ed, but that's nothing to do with the `(T)` cast.