# How to fix 'Unchecked cast from MyClass to T'

Tags: java, list, generics, warnings

I have a method that works, but give me a warning, is there any solution to remove it, cleanly?

- In this method I call the method :
  `<T extends SonarContainPaging> T getSonarObjectFromPage(String url, Map<String, Object> uriVariables, Class<T> klass, List<T> page)`
  That return an object that extends SonarContainPaging.
- I try to add an object that extends SonarContainPaging to my list, but I get a warning.
- The `SonarContainPaging` object has a method `canContinuePaging` that takes a page integer and return a boolean.

The warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from SonarContainPaging to T

```
private <T extends SonarContainPaging> void getSonarListContainingPaging(String url, Map<String, Object> uriVariables, 
        Class<T> klass, List<T> list) {
    int page = 1;
    SonarContainPaging sonarObject = getSonarObjectFromPage(url, uriVariables, klass, page);
    page++;

    list.add((T)sonarObject); // Warning
    while (sonarObject.canContinueLooping(page)) {
        sonarObject = getSonarObjectFromPage(url, uriVariables, klass, page);
        page++;

        list.add((T) sonarObject); // Warning
    }
}
```

Any solution you can think of?

---

The solution given by @Sweeper is to change the type of sonarObject to `T`
The error I made, was assuming that a generic `T` object could not call method from its parent.

Comment: Dirty method: Annotate the method with: @SupressWarnings("unchecked"). Clean method: Check instanceOf before casting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast to generic type (T) gives "unchecked cast" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032215/cast-to-generic-type-t-gives-unchecked-cast-warning)

Comment: @Eran, hi Eran the signature is the question. 
`<T extends SonarContainPaging> T getSonarObjectFromPage(String url, Map<String, Object> uriVariables, Class<T> klass, List<T> page)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `T` as the type here and then you can remove your casts:

```
// before:
// SonarContainPaging sonarObject = getSonarObjectFromPage(url, uriVariables, klass, page);
// after:
T sonarObject = getSonarObjectFromPage(url, uriVariables, klass, page);
```

Since according to your comment, `getSonarObjectFromPage` returns `T`, where `T` is the class you pass it in:

```
<T extends SonarContainPaging> T getSonarObjectFromPage(String url, Map<String, Object> uriVariables, Class<T> klass, List<T> page)
```

In this case you passed the class `klass`, which is a `Class<T>`, so `getSonarObjectFromPage` will return a `T` as well.

Comment: Yes, but I also need to call the method `canContinueLooping`, in the class SonarContainPaging. Still, I don't get why there is a cast warning, since I declared that `<T extends SonarContainPaging>` in the method signature. And for that I need to cast the T object to a SonarContainPaging.

Comment: @HamzaInce Does my answer not work? What error does it produce? The warning occurs because `T` could be any subclass of `SonarContainPaging`. Let's say there is a subclass called `Foo`. You certainly can't cast an instance of `SonarContainPaging` into a `Foo`, can you?

Comment: I didn't expect it to work because I need to call a method in the SonarContainPagging object, but I previously declared that `T extends SonarContainPaging`. I leaned Java better today. thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in general to avoid this warning.

The first is to cast the object to the class:

```
public static <T> T castMe(Class<T> clazz, Object object) {

    return clazz.cast(object);
}
```

The second one is to suppress the warning with an annotation. It's a bit of an unsure way about it but can safely be used when you absolutely know that that specific object can be cast to the generic type in question:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T castMe(Class<T> clazz, Object object) {

    return (T) object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Sweeper already in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56338212/5515060), you can just change the type of `sonarObject` to `T`:

```
T sonarObject;
```

You can also improve your code by using a `do-while` loop which reduces the redundancy you have:

```
private <T extends SonarContainPaging> void getSonarListContainingPaging(String url, Map<String, Object> uriVariables, Class<T> klass, List<T> list) {
    int page = 1;
    T sonarObject;
    do {
        sonarObject = getSonarObjectFromPage(url, uriVariables, klass, page);
        list.add(sonarObject);
    } while (sonarObject.canContinueLooping(++page));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cast method.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-

list.add(klass.cast(sonarObject));