# Avoid `Boolean.box`

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I am calling a java method from `io.netty.bootstrap.BootStrap` that
has the following signature:

```
public <T> B option(ChannelOption<T> option, T value)
```

I am using the following code to call this method:

```
b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
```

And this fails to compile with the following error:

```
Error:(57, 30) type mismatch;
 found   : io.netty.channel.ChannelOption[Boolean]
 required: io.netty.channel.ChannelOption[Any]
Note: Boolean <: Any, but Java-defined class ChannelOption is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
      b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (4)
                         ^
```

I don't fully understand what this says, but I understand it's
complaining about getting a boolean since it was parametrized with
`Any` instead of `Boolean`. So I tried the following code and it
works:

```
b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, Boolean.box(true));
```

This compiles and works. Is there a way to make this prettier without the `box` call?

Can anyone translate that compiler error?

Thank you.

Comment: For the record, when you post to the ML you should mention that you cross-posted to SO to avoid duplicated effort.

Comment: Sorry about that and thank your for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java generics are invariant in scala, so you cannot pass a scala `Boolean` and have the type inferred as you would expect. Explicitly annotating the type should fix it:

```
b.option[java.lang.Boolean](ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what "java generics are invariant"? Or point me some link where I can read about this. Thank you

Comment: Here's a nice writeup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english

Comment: Or annotate the true. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/T93aNh6PYTA/_7wSBGT3phUJ

Comment: I don't understand how variance matters to type inference here. A Scala Boolean is not a java.lang.Boolean, right? `implicitly[Boolean <:< java.lang.Boolean]`  If you need a java boolean you can get it by virtue of autoboxing, but you have to induce the implicit conversion.

Comment: btw, could I define some implicit conversion here instead?