# Java generics: is-A relation to Object

Tags: java, generics, collections, syntax-error

I am trying to understand the features of a **generic class** and its concrete instances, and also the features of a **generic collection**.

suppose I define a generic class: `Stack<T>` 
now I'm trying to use it this way:

```
Stack<String> ts = new Stack<>(5);
Stack<Object> to = new Stack<>(5);
to = ts // compilation error!
```

so obviously `Stack<String>` is not a  `Stack<Object>`.

I got confused when I defined a generic Collection:

```
Set<E> elemnts = new Hashset<>();
```

and noticed that I can use `elements.toString()`! this means that `Set<E> elemnts` extends `Object`!
so whats really going on here?

Comment: Both of your conclusions are correct and don't contradict each other. What are you actually asking?

Comment: In Java, generics are invariant.

Comment: im trying to understand the is-a relationship of generic classes to the Class Object. I was told that this relation dose not work in this case and I want to know what are the implications.

Comment: see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So what are generics in Java exactly?** As mentioned by [dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31357934/4216641), the generic types are compiler enforcements. To be exact, at runtime, the generic types do not exist anymore. They are replaced by `Object` or the upper bound of a generic type. This process is called [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). So, generic types only exist at compile-time.

**Then why can we not cast an `ArrayList<String>` into an `ArrayList<Object>`?** Even though the type parameters stand in a relation (`String` is a `Object`), the generic classes do not. Let me give a simple example. If

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Object> objects = strings;
```

would be possible, if one calls

```
objects.add(new Object());
```

what should happen? Since `strings` can only hold `String`s, Java cannot "put" an `Object` into this list. But on the other hand, if you look at the declaration of `objects` there is nothing hinting, that this should not work. Therefore, Java does not allow conversion between generic classes, even if the generic types stand in a relation.

**But generic types are not present at runtime. So what is the hustle? Should `ArrayList<String>` not really be an `ArrayList<Object>` at runtime and therefore, all of this should not matter?** Well no. Since you know the type at compile-time, you can use certain contracts. For example, when retreiving an element out of an `ArrayList<String>` one can be sure that this retrieved object has the `public char charAt(int)` method (since a `String` has this method). If, for whatever reason, this `ArrayList<String>` would return an `Object` instead of a `String`, one could not call the `charAt(int)` method.

Answer (score 2):

The compilation error doesn't mean that `String` isn't an `Object`, which isn't true. E.g., the following code works just fine:

```
String s = "I am String!";
Object o = s;
```

What the error means is that `Stack<String>` isn't a `Stack<Object>`. For example, you could call `push(new Object())` on a `Stack<Object>`, but obviously not on a `Stack<String>`.

Comment: so this means that Stack<String>. dose extend object but dose not exted Stack<Object>? im trying to figure out the existing is-a relations.

Comment: @netalie yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

For the following:

```
Stack<String> ts = new Stack<>(5);
Stack<Object> to = new Stack<>(5);
to = ts // compilation error!
```

Yes, this compilation fails, because generics are essentially a feature of the compiler enforcing type safety.  Their is actually only one Stack class as far as the virtual machine is concerned.

This statement:

```
Set<E> elemnts = new Hashset<>();
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Set<E> elemnts = new Hashset<E>();
```

The notation was introduced in Java 7 and is sometimes called the 'diamond operator' because of the `<>`.  It is just to remove redundancy.

It is the Set class that is extending Object, just like all classes in Java extend object.

The following holds true for the Class object in your code:

```
 boolean b = ts.getClass() == to.getClass();  // b is true
```

Answer (score 1):

String class is implicitly subclass of Object. Since Object class is super class of all the classes in java. Therefore below statement is valid

```
String x="hello";
Object o= x;
```

But `Stack<String>` is not a sub class of `Stack<Object>`. Therefore code gives compile time error.

```
Stack<String> ts = new Stack<>(5);
Stack<Object> to = new Stack<>(5);
to = ts // compilation error!
```