# Why can't I use List<Truck> as Iterable<Vehicle>?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

Hi I have that error:

```
incompatibles types: List<Car> cannot be converted to Iterable<Iterator>

incompatibles types: List<Truck> cannot be converted to Iterable<Iterator>
```

The class Car extends the class Vehicle. The Truck also extends Vehicle. I have to create the Vehicle class iterable??

```
public static void print(Iterable<Vehicle> it){
    for(Vehicle v: it) System.out.println(v);
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    List<Car> lcotxe = new LinkedList<Car>();
    List<Truck> lcamio = new LinkedList<Truck>();

    print(lcotxe);//ERROR
    print(lcamio);//ERROR


}
```

Comment: You can use generics for that; see https://ideone.com/kTB71Y

Comment: change this `print(Iterable<Vehicle> it)` to this `print(List<Vehicle> it)`

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't compile because `List<Car>` is not a subtype of `Iterable<Vehicle>`.

It is, however, a subtype of `Iterable<? extends Vehicle>`. This is called [covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english).

```
public static void print(Iterable<? extends Vehicle> it){
    for(Vehicle v: it) System.out.println(v);
}
```

You could also choose to make the method generic.

```
public static <A extends Vehicle> void print(Iterable<A> it){
    for(Vehicle v: it) System.out.println(v);
}
```

Comment: this was new to me , thank you @chris-martin !