# Java add list of specific class to list of java.lang.Object works with java 8 streams - why?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, java-8, java-stream

```
public class Test {

    static List<Object> listA = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<TestClass> listB = new ArrayList<>();
        listB.add(new TestClass());

        // not working
        setListA(listB);

        // working
        setListA(listB.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));

        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void setListA(final List<Object> list) {
        listA = list;
    }

}
```

why does it work with streams and does not work for the simple set?

Comment: `setListA(Collections.unmodifiableList(listB))` would also work without the overhead of creating a stream.

Comment: @Radiodef That would do something that is *completely different* from the posted code. (Not related to the type inference etc., but wanted to mention it. passing in a `new ArrayList<Object>(listB)` would be closer to what the posted code does, and would work as well)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first case, it fails because `List<TestClass>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`.<sup>1</sup>

For the second case, we have the following method declarations:

```
interface Stream<T> {
    // ...
    <R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)
}
```

and:

```
class Collectors {
    // ...
    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList()
}
```

This allows Java to infer the generic type parameters from the context.<sup>2</sup> In this case `List<Object>` is inferred for `R`, and `Object` for `T`.

Thus your code is equivalent to this:

```
Collector<Object, ?, List<Object>> tmpCollector = Collectors.toList();
List<Object> tmpList = listB.stream().collect(tmpCollector);
setListA(tmpList);
```

---

<sub>1. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english?noredirect=1).</sub>

<sub>2. See e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) or [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).</sub>

Comment: Does that then mean that the problem is an implicit cast to `Object` in the first "not working" case?

Comment: @Thomas - It's simply that `List<TestClass>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`, and thus the assignment fails.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why List<Object> is inferred for R and Object for T? Especially in the context that `listB.stream()` actually returns a `Stream<TestClass>`, so why would `listB.stream().collect(...)` use Object instead?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou - The rules are complex, and I don't claim to understand them well enough to be able to explain them unambiguously.  See http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html for a better explanation than I could ever give!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Having been a teacher, myself, I always appreciate a clearly knowledgeable engineer saying "I don't know." That's an important thing and I wish more of the people in our world did it.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Type inference uses something called the *target type* of an expression. For a method invocation expression, the target type is typically whatever the return value is assigned to, in this case a parameter of another method. The target type of `collect` is `List<Object>` of `setListA` and the target type of `toList` is `Collector<? super T, A, R>` of `collect`. I think that Javac must be inferring the type of `collect` first here, just based on the fact that this code compiles, but it's been awhile since I've read this section of the JLS.

Comment: @Radiodef: [your example using `unmodifiableList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547122/java-add-list-of-specific-class-to-list-of-java-lang-object-works-with-java-8-st#comment76085259_44547122) would be a simpler starting point when trying to explain the target type inference. The stream/toList collector approach creates a copy, which would be equivalent to `setListA(new ArrayList<>(listB));` which also works since Java 8. In older Java versions, `setListA(new ArrayList<Object>(listB));` would be required.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
setListA(listB);
```

doesn't work because `List` in Java is invariant, meaning `List<TestClass>` **doesn't extends** `List<Object>` when `TestClass` extends `Object`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english?noredirect=1)

This line

```
setListA(listB.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

works because Java infer Object for Collector's generic type from this method signature `setListA(final List<Object> list)` and so you actually pass `List<Object>` there

Comment: I like your explanation of invariance in this case. I was actually wondering about this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the type parameters of Java Generic is **invariance** which means it can't be inherited as type parameters class hierarchy. The common parent of `List<TestClass>` and `List<Object>` is `List<?>`.

[image: generic inheritance]

you can see detailed answer about java generic wildcard from [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) & [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html). for example:

```
 List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<CharSequence> sequences = strings; // can't work
 List<? extends CharSequence> parent1 = strings; // works fine
 List<?> parent2 = strings; // works fine
 //   ^--- is equaivlent to  List<? extends Object>
```

the streams approach is transform a `List<TestClass>` to `List<Object>`. if you want it works without transform a `List` to another `List` by stream. your methods signature should be as below, and the [Collection#addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) also does it in java:

```
List<?> listA = new ArrayList<>();

private static void setListA(List<?> list) {
    listA = list;
}
```