# How does kotlin inheritance work? and how can "*", "in" and "out" be used

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin

I have the below

```
open class Model

class WorkOrder : Model()

//An interface

interface ViewInterface<T : Model> {
    fun notifyDataSuccessful(model: T?, models:ArrayList<T>?)
}

class WorkOrderSystemImpl(val viewInterface: ViewInterface<Model>) {

    fun doSomething() {
        val workOrders: ArrayList<WorkOrder> = ArrayList()
        //the below line complains of type mismatch
        viewInterface.notifyDataSuccessful(workOrders)
    }

}
```

It complains of **type-mismatch** which is quite strange to me, because WorkOrder is a sub-type of Model and i'd expect it to resolve to same type.

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english/8482091 What you're looking for is called "covariance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about the `Generics`'s `invariant` & `covariant`, see Kotlin docs [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).

In short, you can just remember:

> Consumer in, Producer out!

which the `Consumer` & `Producer` is determined from the `List`'s view, that means you should think about the role of you `List`, is it a`Consumer` or `Producer`? In your case, the `models:ArrayList<T>?` is a `Producer`, because it will be used by the implementation of `ViewInterface`, so you should define the `ViewInterface` like this:

```
interface ViewInterface<T: Model> {
    fun notifyDataSuccessful(model: T?, models: ArrayList<out T>?)
}
```

Comment: Okay, adding "out" fixed it...  and thanks for the Consumer & Producer way of thinking, that should fix my thoughts about kotlin generics as i continue this journey