# Java upcasting in container

Tags: java, class, types, containers, covariance

I have two classes parent and child and child extends parent.

```
Parent parent = new Child();
```

Works as expected but the confusion happens when the object is in an container like so.

```
Vector<Parent> vp = new Vector<Child>();
```

This gives the error:

```
incompatible types: Vector<Child> cannot be converted to Vector<Parent>
```

So my question is does the container prevent the implicit typecasting that occurs when we do

```
parent = new Child();
```

Comment: Worth a read: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect that given `Child` subclass of `Parent`, `Vector<Child>` is a subclass of `Vector<Parent>`. This behavior is called `covariance` (things vary together) and it is not the way things work in Java's generic collections. In Java `Vector<Child>` and `Vector<Parent>` are not related (they have an `invariant` relationship).

A more detailed explanation here: [Covariance, Invariance and Contravariance explained in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english)