# Is it possible to have a method signature be a subtype of the interface it implements?

Tags: java, oop, interface

Say I have an interface:

```
public interface IDto {
}
```

and a class that implements this interface:

```
public class UserProfileResponseDto implements IDto {
}
```

In another interface I have:

```
public interface ISortingController {
    public List<IDto> findAll();
}
```

In my concrete controller I have:

```
public List<UserProfileResponseDto> findAll();
```

but its telling me that it must be

```
public List<IDto> findAll();
```

Is there a way that would allow `public List<UserProfileResponseDto> findAll();` as it feels like it should be allowed since `UserProfileResponseDto` implements `IDto`. The reason I ask this question is because I feel that it gives more verbosity the the controller class, which would make it easier to maintain and operate with.

Comment: Declare it as `public List<? extends IDto> findAll();`

Comment: [Covariance, Invariance and Contravariance explained in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a type parameter in your `ISortingController` like this:

```
public interface ISortingController<D extends IDto> {
    public List<D> findAll();
}
```

and your controller implementation needs to say `implements ISortingController< UserProfileResponseDto>`.