# Type Erasure in ArrayList<List<?>> generic call

Tags: java, generics, types, erasure

Can someone explain why the following code does not compile:

`ArrayList<List<?>> arrayList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`

Why is the above code invalid but this one is running fine:

`ArrayList<?> items = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`

Comment: `arrayList.add(Arrays.asList(1,2,3))` is supported for an `ArrayList<List<?>>`. So an `ArrayList<List<?>>` cannot be an `ArrayList<List<String>>`.

Comment: Wild cards are only matched one level deep.

Comment: Related: [Variance, covariance and invariance explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english) and [What is PECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with simple lists. Integer is a subclass of Number, so you can assign Integer to a Number:

```
Integer i = 42;
Number n = i;  // Ok
```

Now, let's have a `List<Number>`. Shouldn't we be able to put a `List<Integer>` there?

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Fails
```

No, it fails. Why? Because generics in Java are invariant, that means for any two different types T1 and T2 neither `List<T1>` is a subtype of `List<T2>` nor `List<T2>` is a subtype of `List<T1>` 
regardless of relations between T1 and T2. Ok, this formally explains why the above assignment is invalid, but what is the logic behind this?

The `List<Number>` should be able to hold any number, that means that if we have a declaration

```
List<Number> numbers;
```

then we should be able to do `number.add(Integer(42))`, `number.add(Double(Math.PI))` and any other `number.add(subClassOfNumber)`. However, if the above assignment

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // ?
```

would be valid, then `numbers` would now hold the list, which is only capable of storing Integers, so `numbers.add(anyNumberButInteger)` would have failed, which violates the contract of `List<Number>`.

It is possible to create a list, which will hold instances of some subclass of Number:

```
List<? extends Number> list = Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7, 8);  // Ok
```

You can read this list without a problem:

```
System.out.println(list.get(2));   // 7
```

However you can't put anything there except null, because it's not possible to know the exact type of list elements at compile time and thus is not possible to make the check for safety:

```
List<? extends Number> list = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? 
                                   new ArrayList<Integer>() : 
                                   new ArrayList<Double>();
list.add(null);      // Ok
list.add(Double.valueOf(3.1415));    //  Fails, because we don't know if Double(3.1415) is actually compatible with elements of the list
```

Well, now to your example:

```
List<List<?>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

In order this assignment to work you actually need to have on the left side  a `List<? extends List<String>>`, but since Java generic is invariant, the only type which extends `List<String>` is `List<String>` itself, so the only valid combination is

```
List<List<String>> listOfListsOfStrings = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

It is possible to create a variable which represent a list, which is composed of some lists by using raw types:

```
List<? extends List> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); // Compiles, but loses generics. DON'T DO THIS!
List<String> listOfStrings = listOfLists.get(0);                  // Compiles, even would work as expected assuming we populated listOfLists correctly
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = listOfLists.get(0);                // Compiles, but does not work as expected (fail at runtime when accessing elements)
```

**TLDR:** the only generic class which is super/extends `List<String>` is `List<String>`, so `List<some class which extends List<String>>` automatically means `List<List<String>>`.