# Pass subclass of class as type parameter (type parameter is subclass)

Tags: java, scala, generics, scala-java-interop, f-bounded-polymorphism

let's consider:

```
public class Text extends BinaryComparable
    implements WritableComparable<BinaryComparable> {
```

We can see that `Text` **is** `BinaryComparable`.

Then, let's consider

```
@InterfaceAudience.Public
@InterfaceStability.Stable
public interface WritableComparable<T> extends Writable, Comparable<T> {
```

I have some class in Scala:

```
trait MyClass[A <: WritableComparable[A]] {
```

It is not possible to create

```
MyClass[Text] = new MyClass[Text]()
```

due to type mismatch.  Why? After all, `Text` is `BinaryComparable`  How to resolve it?

Comment: `MyClass` only takes one parameter, also which error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add one more type parameter

```
trait MyClass[B >: A, A <: WritableComparable[B]]

val mc: MyClass[BinaryComparable, Text] = new MyClass[BinaryComparable, Text] {}
```

On contrary to `trait MyClass[A <: WritableComparable[_ >: A]]` this doesn't produce `illegal cyclic reference`.

Alternatively you can define bounds in `MyClass` as

```
trait MyClass[B, A <: B with WritableComparable[B]]

val mc: MyClass[BinaryComparable, Text] = new MyClass[BinaryComparable, Text] {}
```

You can even exclude `B` with existential type (as **@user** proposed)

```
trait MyClass[A <: B with WritableComparable[B] forSome { type B }]

val mc: MyClass[Text] = new MyClass[Text] {}
```

Such existential types will be deprecated in Scala 3

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html

Comment: Being honestly, I don't understand it exactly. `A <: WritableComparable[B]` guarantess that `A` has method like `compare(T o)`. `B >: A` does mean that `A extends B`. Why does it guarantee that `A` will be comparable to all `supertypes` of A? (called as `B` here)

Comment: In other words, it should work with `MyClass[B, A <: WritableComparable[B]]` as well.

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. Basically, we expressed that `A` has method `compareTo(B o)` and `B` is supertype of `A`. It does mean that we can compare: `new A().compareTo(*)` where * is arbitrary object being instance of supertype of `A`.

Comment: @tomek.xyz It's just generalization of `Text extends BinaryComparable implements WritableComparable<BinaryComparable>`. `Text` is `A`, `BinaryComparable` is `B`. `Text extends... implements...` can be written as `A <: B with WritableComparable[B]`. So you can introduce either `trait MyClass[B >: A, A <: WritableComparable[B]]` or `trait MyClass[B, A <: B with WritableComparable[B]]`.

Answer (score 3):

`WritableComparable[BinaryComparable]` is not the same as or a supertype of `WritableComparable[Text]`, as `WritableComparable` is invariant in `T` (Java generics doesn't really have covariance or contravariance).

If `WritingComparable` had been declared as `trait WritingComparable[-A]`, then it would [compile](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WDzOzte9QoGgFRPCdcF9mw).

Your last code snippet does not make much sense, though, as `MyClass` does not take 2 type parameters (as Luis Miguel Mejia Suarez mentioned). You shouldn't get a type mismatch error, it should tell you you have too many parameters. I think you meant only `MyClass[Text]`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english)'s a question asking about invariance, contravariance, and covariance.

Comment: I edited it. Can you tell me, how to repair it? Is it possible?

Comment: @tomek.xyz I tried using `[_ >: A]`, but that [doesn't work](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/A2mYcLkuQ4Of1zKZihqykg).  An [existential type](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DyVv1M1NRue71ZffdqrfLg) may work, but it's hacky, and I'd really recommend rethinking your design, if you have any control over `MyClass`'s type parameters.