# how to understand `? extends T` is convariant?

Tags: java

I have read some article about generic covariant, and a learn a common knowledge about
covariant and contravariant describe how the subtype relation is affected by type transformations. That is, if A and B are types, f is a type transformation, and ≤ the subtype relation (i.e. A ≤ B means that A is a subtype of B), we have

- f is covariant if A ≤ B implies that f(A) ≤ f(B)
- f is contravariant if A ≤ B implies that f(B) ≤ f(A)
- f is invariant if neither of the above holds

as we know, `? extends T` is covariant, so we can say:
because of `? extends Number ≤ Number`
so `List<? extends Number> ≤ List<Number>`, and this means `List<? extends Number>` is a subtype of `List<Number>`

```java
List<? extends Number> a1 = null;
List<Number> a2 = null;
a2 = a1; // compile error
a1 = a2; // compile success
```

so why `a1 = a2` can be compiled, but `a2 = a1` can't.
Don't `List<? extends Number>` is a subtype of `List<Number>` means `a2 = a1` ?
wait and hope your answer !

Comment: "... this means `List<? extends Number>` is a subtype of `List<Number>`" — No, it doesn't. `List<Number>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`.

Comment: No, `List<? extends Number>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>` (don't of subtypes and the like when dealing with generics) but it can be assigned any list whose generic type is `Number` or a subtype of that. So `a2 = a1` fails because `a2` explicitly expects a `List<Numbe>` while `a1` could actually be a `List<Integer>` etc. which doesn't fit.

Comment: does covariant means type relationship transform ? @khelwood

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "type relationship transform"

Comment: Ah, did you read "type transformation" from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8482091/5133585)? Your reasoning is not sound. What do you define `f` as? You seem to have defined it as `f(A) = List<A>`, but this is an invariant transformation, so you can't apply that rule about covariant transformations.

Comment: If instead you define `f(A) = List<? extends A>`, which is a covariant transformation. Then you can apply the rule to, say, `Integer` and `Number`. `Integer ≤ Number`, so `List<? extends Integer> ≤ List<? extends Number>` holds.

Comment: so Is there any specific result for  `List<? extends Number> arr = new ArrayList<Number>()`, why List<Number> is subtype of List<? extends Number>, is it  because of  Number is only an element of  `? extends Number`? how to explain... @Thomas @Sweeper @khelwood

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain a little more: `<? extends Number>` is a bounded *wildcard* so this is *not a type* but more like a placeholder. It states that the actual generic type can be `Number` or a subtype.

So the following would be valid:

```
List<? extends Number> numberList = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<? extends Number> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

You can also assign them:

```
integerList = numberList; 
numberList = doubleList;
doubleList = integerList;
```

Why does this work? Because the compiler imposes some restrictions, e.g. you are not allowed to add elements to those lists (actually no method taking a wildcard parameter would be allowed).

Why can't you add to those? Because after the above reassignments a `doubleList.add(Double.valueOf(1.5)` would be fatal because the variable would actually point to a list that was defined to only contain integers (`new ArrayList<Integer>()`).

`List<? extends Number>` actually just tells the compiler that the list allows elements that extend `Number` you could retrieve those elements and assign them to `Number`:

```
for( Number element : numberList ) { ... }
for( Number element : integerList ) { ... }
for( Number element : doubleList) { ... }
```

Why is `List<Number>` different? Because it only defines that all elements are instances of `Number` and thus adding and retrieving numbers are allowed.

The assignment `List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>()` is not allowed because you could still call `numberList.add(Double.valueOf(1.23))` which would be logically invalid (see above).

Since `List<? extends Number> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();` is valid, `List<Number> numberList = integerList;` is not - this would transitively allow invalid assignments which the compiler should prevent (that's why you use generics).

Comment: https://pingfangx.github.io/java-tutorials/java/generics/subtyping.html
this article say List<Number> is a subtype of List<? extends Number>, but not have any explain, maybe it is an appointment.

Comment: @wanglong well, you could think of that relation in terms of types and subtypes but you need to be aware that those behave differently than normal types. Even though `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`, a `List<Integer>` is not a "subtype" of `List<Number>` and even though you could say that in some sense a `List<Number>` is a "subtype" of `List<? extends Number>` you can't use both the same way.