# Java incompatible type <A> cannot be converted to wildcard parameter <? extends B> inside HashMap<>

Tags: java, hashmap, type-conversion

Recently I have come across the following error during compilation:

```
error: incompatible types: HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Object, Consumer<A>>> cannot be converted
to HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Object, Consumer<? extends B>>>
```

In this code, class `A` is a direct subclass of `B`.

This error occurred in the following snippet:

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Object, Consumer<A>>> item = new HashMap<>();
HashSet<HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Object, Consumer<? extends B>>>> set = new HashSet();
set.add(item);
```

In attempting to resolve the error I have already tried removing the `? extends` bit from the `HashMap` inside of the `HashSet`, but the compiler kept throwing the error.

Comment: `A is a direct subclass of B.` This looks like a direct application of "generics aren't covariant."  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english

Answer (score 0):

`Consumer<A>`  and `Consumer<? extends B>` are totally different  , in fact `Consumer<? extends B>` can be `Consumer<C>` where `C` is another class who extends B.

The same with `Consumer<A>`  and `Consumer<B>` they are not the same thing, an instance of `B` class is not an instance of `A` class, so deleting the `? extends` still give you a compile time error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    static class Lion extends Animal {
    }
    static class Animal {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? extends Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        animals .add(new Lion()); // DOES NOT COMPILE 

        // at compile time , our List(reference) may be a List of Animal or List of Lion , not a List of both of them
        
        // using ? extends Animal to refer the ArrayList instance 
        // we cannot add a Lion to an ArrayList of Animal

        animals .add(new Animal()); // DOES NOT COMPILE

        // the same using the ? extends Animal as reference 
       // we cannot add an animal to an ArrayList of Lion
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this is incorrect. `A` is a subclass of `B`, so `Consumer<A>` is a subtype of `Consumer<? extends B>`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are wrong, Dawood, and in Java generics `Consumer<A>` and `Consumer<? extends B>` are in fact totally different types.  Can you cite sources for your assertion?

Comment: You're welcome to be "pretty sure" about whatever you like, @markspace, but what I said is _literally_ what `extends` inside the `< >` means.  You can test this out for yourself by writing a little program where `A extends B` and where you use a variable of type `Consumer<? extends B>` to refer to an object of type `Consumer<A>`.   I have done this myself literally hundreds of times.  This answer is incorrect, despite someone upvoting it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem can you please take a look at the updated answer, i tried to add an example , you can copy past it in your IDE.

Comment: Sure.  The reason why `animals.add(new Lion())` doesn't compile in your new example is because although `List<Lion>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Animal>`, it's not the other way around.  So you can't add a `Lion` to `animals`, because based on the type of `animals`, it could reference a `List<Tiger>`.  You are trying to do something to a variable of type `List<? extends Animal>` that can only be done to specific subtypes of `List<? extends Animal>`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem , it is the same problem of the question , reference using Consumer<? extends B> make the compiler prevent any add of type Consumer<A>

Comment: No, the problem in the question is much more complex, because the Consumer is inside a HashMap of HashMaps.  If you were to remove the HashMaps from the question, you wouldn't get that error.  You'd never see  `Consumer<A> cannot be converted
to Consumer<? extends B>`, because a `Consumer<A>` is in fact a `Consumer<? extends B>`.

Comment: On the other hand, you _could_ get `HashMap<Object, Consumer<A>> cannot be converted to HashMap<Object, Consumer<? extends B>>`  if the code in the question had just a single level of `HashMap`.  Because if you could convert a  `HashMap<Object, Consumer<A>>` to a `HashMap<Object, Consumer<? extends B>>`, you could then put a `Consumer<C>` in it, (where `C` is another subtype of `B`), and that's something you can never do to a `HashMap<Object, Consumer<A>>`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Obviously you’re correct that `Consumer<A>` is matched by `Consumer<? extends B>`, but I disagree with your use of “subtype.”  I think the use of that word is causing some confusion here.  The fact that A is a subtype of B does not imply that `Consumer<A>` is a subtype of `Consumer<? extends B>`.  A more illustrative example is that one cannot do the same operations with `List<? extends B>` that one can do with `List<A>`.

Comment: @VGR You are mistaken.  The fact that one cannot do the same operations with `List<? extends B>` that one can do with `List<A>` means that `List<? extends B>` is not a subtype of `List<A>`.  It's a supertype.   The fact that every `List<A>` is also a `List<? extends B>` is the very definition of a subtype.  You're getting subtype and supertype reversed.