# Does method Optional.of do a type conversion?

Tags: java, generics

```java
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Optional<Y> opY = Optional.of( new Y() ) ;
        // ERROR
        Optional<X> opX = (Optional<X>) opY ;
    }

}

class X {}
class Y extends X {}
```

As in the code above, because `Optional<Y>` is not an `Optional<X>`, there is an Error.

But why is there no problem with the following code?

```java
Optional<X> opX = Optional.of( new Y() ) ;
```

Comment: Generic are not covariant (they are invariant).  Some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant  There is *NO* type conversion in Java, except for primitives like `int` and `float`.

Comment: The reason why `Optional<X> opX = Optional.of( new Y() ) ;` works is because class types are covariant.  Since `Y` is a type of `X`, it can be placed in a generic `X` object because it's the same type.

Comment: This isn't specific to Optionals, this is the behavior of generics in java. This also doesn't compile, for the same reason: List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: Fair @erosb, though I assumed that was already understood.  More hairy details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java, the basic type system is so-called *covariant*. Covariance means 'any subtype of X is acceptable anywhere an X is needed'. This is likely to be not surprising to you:

```
Integer i = 5;
Number n = i;
```

The above is perfectly fine; the compiler accepts it with no warnings or errors and it runs as you'd expect.

However, the stuff in the `<>` **do not work that way**. They are invariant:

```
List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> n = i;
```

The above *does not compile*. That *is* usually surprising to anybody who isn't familiar with the intricacies of generics.

The reason the above doesn't compile is: Because if it *did* compile you could do evil things that break generics. Witness:

```
List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> n = i;
Double d = 4.5;
n.add(d);
```

The last 2 lines cannot possibly fail, because java itself is defined so that they cannot: the `add()` method requires a `Number`, and as per java spec, all Double values are Numbers, so `n.add(d)` must necessarily compile. However, java is pass-by-reference - count the `new`. There's just one `new` here, so there is just one list. Both `n` and `i` are just references to the same list (it's like an address book - 2 address books, both with the same address on it. That means there's just the one house). So, when you add `d` to `n`, you're also adding it to `i` - but now we have a real problem on our hands, because `i` says it is a list of integers, and there's a double in there.

This is **why** generics are invariant. Because of the fundamental nature of types.

Specifically the problem with lists shows up when you attempt to add stuff to it: If you had a list that, hypothetically, had no way to add anything to it (`add` doesn't exist, nor does `addAll`), then there wouldn't be an issue here.

With `Optional` it gets confusing. The problem is: Optional is like that hypothetical list - you can't change it once it is made, so there would *appear* to be no problem with treating an `Optional<Integer>` as an `Optional<Number>`, and indeed if you treat `Optional` as more of a type decoration, you'd expect the relationship between `Optional<Number>` and `Optional<Integer>` to match the relationship between `Number` and `Integer`, but **that is not what Optional is, and the java generics type system cannot fix this for you** - the typing system has no idea that Optional is immutable. Hence, it cannot look the other way here and won't let you treat an `Optional<Integer>` as an `Optional<Number>`. Even though your brain knows nothing will actually go wrong, javac doesn't know that. And even if it did: Imagine in some future update, `Optional` grows a `.set` method. Yeah, sure, that'd ruin the thing, but 'is immutable' is neither a property encoded in the type system nor is it considered something that de-facto is backwards incompatible. So, javac needs to operate under the assumption that *could* one day happen.

```
Optional<X> opX = Optional.of( new Y() ) ;
```

So, this works because the compiler parses that as `Optional.<X>of( new Y() )`, and `new Y()` is an expression that is valid where an X is required.

Whereas in your first snippet, you have an `Optional<Y>` and are asking for it to be treated as an `Optional<X>`, which java won't do, because generics don't work like that, *even though* with `Optional` the problem that javac is foreseeing (adding a `Double` to a `List<Integer>`) can't happen with Optional instances.

It's one of the many reasons you shouldn't be using Optional at all, or at least  very sparingly.

Note that you can opt into covariance:

```
List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> n = i; // this compiles just fine!
n.add(... nope ...);
```

The above snippet now is different: The first 2 lines are fine (an expression of type `List<Integer>` is valid when a `List<? extends Number>` is required), but you can't call `.add` on a `List<? extends Anything>`, at all, except with the literal `null` and only because that literal is all types at once.

You can do the same thing with Optional, and there are no methods that are 'handicapped' when you do that (like the way `.add` and `.addAll` on a `List<? extends ..>` basically are removed, optional has no such methods - none that take a `T`, as those methods can't be used if the generics bound is `<?>` or `<? extends ..>`:

```
Optional<Y> optY = new Optional<>(new Y());
Optional<? extends X> optX = optY; // compiles fine
X x = optX.get(); // compiles fine.
```

The `? extends X` doesn't feel useful, and indeed it makes no meaningful difference to what you can do when you dereference `optX`, but it tells the compiler all is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your second example `Optional.of()` expects an `X` and `new Y()` *is* an `X`.

But, as you state, an `Optional<Y>` is not an `Optional<X>`, hence the first example doesn't work.

More generally a `A<X>` is not a `A<Y>`, no matter what `X` and `Y` are.