# What does this mean in java <TTask, TList>?

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java, and I already searched the internet. But I couldn't get the right
Here is my questions about next code:

```
protected <TTask, TList> void get(
        final List<TList> list,
        final Class<? extends AbstractAsyncTask<TTask>> asyncTaskClass,
        final Class<TList> myTypeClass,
        final Object... constructorParams)
```

1. What does `<TTask, TList>` mean?
2. What does `Class<? extends AbstractAsyncTask<TTask>>` mean?

Thank you for your any site or hinder or example.

Comment: [Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Thank you guys. But could give more detail about my questions?

Comment: @AmyWuGo I strongly encourage you to go through the tutorial. Generics are all over java and a good understanding of them will help you no end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find everything about your problem in [the generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). 
But to give you atleast "something"

```
protected <TTask, TList> void get(
            final List<TList> list,
            final Class<? extends AbstractAsyncTask<TTask>> asyncTaskClass,
            final Class<TList> myTypeClass,
            final Object... constructorParams)
```

is a [Generic Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

1) `TTask` and `TList` are called [Type Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). They are like variables that hold any type (`String`, `Integer`, `AnyUserDefinedClass`) that you pass. If you pass

`List<String> list`

as the `get` method's first argument, all the occurence of `TList` inside the method will be replaced with `String`

2) `Class<? extends AbstractAsyncTask<TTask>>` particularly the part `<? extends AbstractAsyncTask<TTask>>`  means any subclass of `AbstractAsyncTask<TTask>` (or anything that extends `AbstractAsyncTask<TTask>`) can be placed here, where `TTask` is again, a variable that holds any type that you pass.

Further Read : [Covariance and Contravariance in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501513/1767366)