# Java - do covariance and contravariance exist?

Tags: java, generics, covariance, contravariance

I got a little bit confused the other day when it comes to generics and covariance/contravariance. I know C# specifies covariant/contravariant type parameters, but is there really a similar concept in Java?

I understand you can declare:

```
List<? extends String> l = ...
List<? super String> l2 =...
```

and now l can take list of `MyString`, add method is not allowed etc. while l2 can take `List<Object>` and add String to it, but cannot get any element, as described here [Covariance- contravariance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java). This, however, is simply declaring a List with a type parameter that accepts subtyes/supertypes, not doing "proper" covariance like:

```
Iterable<Animal> a = new Iterable<Dog>();
```

Am I confused or does Java simply not support proper covariance definitions? Thanks.

Comment: It should be `Iterable<? extends Animal> a = new Iterable<Dog>();` assuming `Dog extends Animal` and `Iterable<T>`

Comment: Yes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java

Comment: I meant the Iterable exactly like that, if Java allowed covariant type param of course

Answer (score -2):

Java's type variance is at the use site, not at the declaration site. Say we have a type declaration

```
interface List<E>
```

we can use it covariantly (in original syntax)

```
List<+Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

the `+` annotation on the type variable makes the parameterized type covariant.

That is not bad at all. We can have contraviant `List<-Animal>` too. It is more flexible.

UNFORTUNATELY, Java designers overestimated the stupidity of Java programmers, they think the single letter symbol +/- will drive us mad; that we must see english words to understand what's going on. And it was still the time in Java that verbosity is to be celebrated. So we get this syntax

```
List<? extends Animal>
```

I think it is absolutely retarded.