# Why is the implicit cast of ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> to Iterable<Iterable<T>> impossible?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I would like to know the reason why Java can't cast `ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>` to `Iterable<Iterable<T>>` implicitly.
My question is not about how to do it explicitly.

Why does the following code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
  public Test() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Test>> arr = new ArrayList();
    Iterable<Iterable<Test>> casted = arr;
  }
}
```

raise the following error during compilation?

```
Test.java:7: error: incompatible types: ArrayList<ArrayList<Test>> cannot be converted to Iterable<Iterable<Test>>
```

Comment: Because you could then do `casted.add(new LinkedList());`, or add anything else that implements `Iterable`, even though `casted` is only supposed to hold objects of `ArrayList<Test>`.

Comment: No, I could not do `arr.add(new LinkedList());` because arr is still an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Test>>`.
I could not do `casted.add(new LinkedList());` either, because Iterable doesn't implement add.

Comment: Okay, yes. But what would happen if you casted to `List<List<Test>>` instead? That has an `add` method. For the `Iterable` case, there's semantically no issue (because `Iterable`s are read-only), but for the general case, it allows you to violate the inner template's type, so Java won't allow you to do it.

Comment: So far these answers have mentioned how to work around the problem, but they have not explained the reason why the workaround is necessary.

Comment: Java documentation actually provides a very good general explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList` is `Iterable`, you're right, so `ArrayList<ArrayList<Test>>` is `Iterable<ArrayList<Test>>`.

BUT `Iterable<Iterable<Test>>` is not `Iterable<ArrayList<Test>>`, because in this case you, of course, can't explicitly add something to `Iterable`, but it's possible situation, that you can (with other examples), so you may add, for example, `Set<Test>` within it, so this would break `arr`.

You can work around this with using bounded generics:

```
Iterable <? extends Iterable<Test>> casted = arr;
```

So, when you run `iterator()` on `casted` you'll get `Iterator<? extends Iterable<Test>>` and withing every `next()` you'll get `? extends Iterable<Test>`, which is `Iterable<Test>`.

You should read something about [covariance and countervariance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java) to get this.

Comment: @njzk2 No, we can't, compiler will prevent it, because it cannot be sure (and that's not true), that expansion for `? extends Iterable<Test>` is exactly `HashSet`.

Comment: I find your "BUT" assertion confusing. You write, "[I]n this case you, of course, can't explicitly add something to `Iterable`". No one is trying to do so. Perhaps you meant to write, "`Iterable<Iterable<Test>>` is not an `Iterable<ArrayList<Test>>` instead. That would make more sense.

Comment: @seh Exactly, I'll fix an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because how Generics work. You would have to use:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Test>> arr = new ArrayList();
Iterable<? extends Iterable<Test>> casted = arr;
```

`ArrayList<ArrayList>` is not compatible with `Iterable<Iterable>` because generics are strict. `ArrayList` is not `Iterable`, but it is `? extends Iterable`

However, this has limitations. Consider

```
ArrayList<? extends Iterable<Test>> casted = arr;
```

This work. But now, `casted` is bound to basically no type. You cannot call `add` on it, because no type is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a few similar examples:

```
public final class Test {
  public Test() {
    final ArrayList<ArrayList<Test>> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<? extends Iterable<Test>> valueTypeRef = a1;
    final Iterable<? extends Iterable<Test>> spinalTypeRef = valueTypeRef;

    final ArrayList<Iterable<Test>> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
    final Iterable<Iterable<Test>> r2 = a2;
  }
}
```

In the first example with `a1`, you can see the valid references we can form, first generalizing the value type, and then generating the container's type (the "spine", when talking about a sequence). The second example (`a2`) shows how starting with a value type of `Iterable` allows the reference type you'd like to form without trouble.

Your question boils down to why `valueTypeRef` can't be of type `ArrayList<Iterable<Test>>`, and why we need to use an *upper-bounded wildcard* instead. In Java, type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Test>>` has no relationship with type `ArrayList<Iterable<Test>>`, even though `ArrayList<Test>>` is a subtype of `Iterable<Test>`. Forming the `valueTypeRef` looks for this would-be relationship for its implicit cast, but no such relationship exists, even if you as the programmer can see that it *should* exist.

The only way that Java allows you to take advantage of this subtype relationship is with *wildcards*, as explained here in [*Wildcards and Subtyping* in *The Java Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html). We need to introduce an upper-bounded wildcard (here, `ArrayList<? extends Iterable<Test>>`) to tell the type system that we expect our new reference's value type to be a subtype of its referent's value type.

Type parameters without a wildcard are neither *covariant* nor *contravariant*; even if function parameters and return types allow the normal substitutions along subtype and supertype axes, the generic types themselves (e.g. `ArrayList<ArrayList<Test>>` and `ArrayList<Iterable<Test>>`) can only participate in these substitutions with wildcards.

The resulting type (again, `ArrayList<? extends Iterable<Test>>`) precludes use of any mutating functions that would insert some value into the list that's indeed an `Iterable<Test>` but *not* an `ArrayList<Test>`. The resulting reference type is *covariant* with its referent, meaning loosely that it's safe to read through, but not safe to write through.

Answer (score -1):

## Bad solution

If anyone is interested, here is how I had solved my problem. But this is **a workaround**, that doesn't explain why the first snippet didn't work:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
  public Test() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Test>> arr = new ArrayList();
    Iterable<Iterable<Test>> casted = (Iterable<Iterable<Test>>)(Iterable<?>)arr;
  }
}
```

This is an unsafe operation. In this case, no harm will be made because Iterable are read-only, but this method allows you to cast an `ArrayList<ArrayList>` to an `ArrayList<LinkedList>` for instance, and thus it can break `arr`.

## Good solution

There is no good solution to cast an `ArrayList<ArrayList>` to an `Iterable<Iterable>`, for the reason explained above. But you can safely (and implicitly) cast an `ArrayList<ArrayList>` to an `Iterable<? extends Iterable>`, and work on your variables of type `Iterable<? extends Iterable>` as you would have on an `Iterable<Iterable>`.

And you can implicitly an `Iterable<Iterable>` is an `Iterable<? extends Iterable>`.

Comment: **Do not do this!** This code is generically unsafe, as you can add `List`s that are not `ArrayList`s, breaking the type safety of `arr`, which is only allowed to contain `ArrayList`s. This is as bad as saying `List<String> l1 = null; List<Object> l2 = (List<Object>) (List<?>) l1; l2.add(new Object()); // l1 contains an instance of Object!`.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say `l1 = new ArrayList<String>;`, not `null`, but you get the picture.