# +- Signs in Generic Declaration in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I was looking at the documentation for PartialFunction in [this link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction):

```
trait PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends (A) ⇒ B
```

Maybe someone can help clarify the significance of the plus and minus signs in the generic declaration?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

"+" and "-" mean [covariant and contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674090/1809978) types respectively. In short, it means that:

`PartialFunction[-A1, +B1]` <: `PartialFunction[-A2, +B2]` only if `A1 :> A2` and `B1 <: B2`, where `<:` is a subtyping relationship.

"-" usually applied for input parameters, "+" for output - in C# they even use respective keywords `in` and `out`. There is also some more primitive [generic variance support in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java) built up on existential types - actually you can do it using `_ <: SomeType` (covariance) or abstract type members `type T <: SomeType` in Scala as well.

Without modifiers `PartialFunction[A1, B1]` would have no direct relationship to a `PartialFunction[A2, B2]` (in other words, it would be invariant).

P.S. There are also some restrictions applied to such types, like covariant("+") type can't be in contravariant position (you can only return it from a method) and vice-versa. This is done in order to support [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and naturally understandable by "in"/"out" interpretation.

Also, it worth noting that `A => B` (syntax sugar for `Function1`) itself is using co-/contra-variance:

```
 trait Function1 [-T1, +R] extends AnyRef
```

As those functions can be extended through sub-typing which makes them theoretically partial as well (though it’s not how Scala treats these) - even technically “total” FunctionN in Scala could be extended, redefined, return null and so on.

Answer (score 23):

It's covariance and contravariance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Basically it says for Generic types how inheritance will work.
Easy sample from Scala is - `trait Seq[+A]`
Because of the + , the code

```
val s: Seq[Person] = Seq[Student]()
```

will compile because Student extends Person. Without the + it won't work

A bit more complex sample -

```
class C[-A, +B] {
  def foo(param: A): B = ???
}

class Person(val name: String)

class Student(name: String, val university: String) extends Person(name)

val sample: C[Student, Person] = new C[Person, Student]
```

Answer (score 8):

To supplement the other answers, here is a link to the documentation for variances on the scala-lang site:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html