# Scala Set, what is happening with invariant types?

Tags: scala, invariance

While doing a refactor in a scala application I came across a situation where changing from List to Set raised a question which I didn't have before. I have some idea about variance, but I would like to understand what does it mean for the compiler exactly.

I had something similar to this, which compiles and works just fine:

```
case class MyClassList(s: List[Any])
val myList = List(("this", false)) // List[(String, Boolean)]
val listWorks = MyClassList(myList)
```

Then I changed my list to set:

```
case class MyClassSet(s: Set[Any])
val mySet = Set(("this", false)) // Set[(String, Boolean)]
val setFails = MyClassSet(mySet)
```

At this point, creating an object of MyClassSet type is no longer ok with me passing a Set as the argument, even when it accepts a Set of Any. Now, it got a bit confusing when the following worked (note that the set is "the same" as the previous mySet):

```
val setWorks1 = MyClassSet(Set(("this", false)))
```

I believe that the simple explanation is that the compiler is inferring mySet val as a Set[(String, Boolean)], but when I instantiate it directly in the arguments list of setWorks1, because it accepts a Set[Any], the compiler is inferring it as a Set[Any]. This makes the first example fail and the second one pass. These ones also work, which points to the previous being correct:

```
val setWorks2 = MyClassSet(mySet.toSet[Any])
val mySetOfAny: Set[Any] = Set(("this", false), ("that", true), ("other", false))
val setWorks3 = MyClassSet(mySetOfAny)
```

The actual error shown by the compiler is:

```
Error:(15, 55) type mismatch;
found   : Set[(String, Boolean)]
required: Set[Any]
Note: (String, Boolean) <: Any, but trait Set is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: (...)
```

Lists and Sets are defined as follows:

```
type List[+A]  = scala.collection.immutable.List[A]
type Set[A]    = immutable.Set[A]
```

- Is this difference in the type variance which allows me to pass a List of a "more restricted type than Any" as the argument but not a in the case of 
  Set?
- Is this difference only preventing the casting or conversion between types?
- Is this mostly a compiler "limitation" or an expected property of an invariant type?
- Are there any other differences between invariant types "in practice" or do they boil down to casting such as this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) It's explained here:
    [Why is Scala's immutable Set not covariant in its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676615/why-is-scalas-immutable-set-not-covariant-in-its-type)

Basically, Set[T] is also a `Function1[T, Boolean]`. The signature of `Function1` is `[-In, +Out]`, so `T` couldn't be both `+T` and `-T` at the same time as scala doesn't allow bivariance (it would significantly weaken type system).

2) You can easily cast it using `.toSet[Any]` (which is a wrapper over `asInstanceOf`). There is also a way to [skip variance check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454281/when-is-uncheckedvariance-needed-in-scala-and-why-is-it-used-in-generictravers).

3, 4) It's expected property of generic (polymorphic) types. They can be invariant/covariant/contravariant (not only) and it's formally described by simple rules. You can read explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27627891/1809978

Comment: Accepting your answer since after reading all the other replies in the linked answers I got my brain around it. The actual difference in 1) explains well why Set is invariant (also because there is implemented using Maps which have an invariant key. Thanks