# Adding String,ArrayList, etc objects to List<Object>

Tags: java, generics

I have a data structure `Map < String, Map < ConfigKey, ConfigValue<Object > > >`. This is like a `Map` of "namespace" to `Map` of "key" to "value". My parser reads config file and dynamically decides if the value should be treated as `String` or `ArrayList`.

I see error adding `ArrayList` to above data structure. Please show me how to fix this.

```
private Map<String, Map<ConfigKey, ConfigValue<Object>>> configuration = new HashMap<String, Map<ConfigKey, ConfigValue<Object>>>();
:
configuration.get(groupName).put(new ConfigKey(key), new ConfigValue<Object>(override, value)); // works
:
configuration.get(groupName).put(new ConfigKey(key), new ConfigValue<List>(override, Arrays.asList(values))); // does not work
```

Comment: "I am facing trouble" is not a good error description. Please amend.

Answer (score 3):

```
ConfigValue<List> is not a ConfigValue<Object>.
```

[Read more about covariance and contravariance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java) or in [programming in general.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))

This would fix it

```
private Map<String, Map<ConfigKey, ConfigValue<? extends Object>>> configuration = new HashMap<String, Map<ConfigKey, ConfigValue<? extends Object>>>();
```

or

```
Map<String, Map<ConfigKey, ConfigValue<?>>>
```

And please avoid [raw-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) in your code.