# Java generic upper bounded wildcard error

Tags: java, generics

I have the following entities in my domain model:

```
class Point {
    public String details;

    public Point() {
        details = "empty";
    }

    public Point(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}

class BasicPoint<X, Y> extends Point {
    public X x;
    public Y y;

    public BasicPoint() {}

    public BasicPoint(X x, Y y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Collector<T> {
    T elem;

    public void collect(T elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
    }
}
```

I want to apply operations on data and return that data as Point or BasicPoint, as declared above, but the compiler is complaining with the following error although OUT extends Point:

```
class Operator<OUT extends Point> {
    public Collector<OUT> operate(Collector<OUT> collector) {

        // compile error, collect(OUT) cannot be applied to BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>
        collector.collect(new BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>(1,2));

        return collector;
    }
}
```

Main method should look like:

```
Collector<BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>> c = new Collector<>();
c = new Operator<BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>>().operate(c);
System.out.println(c.elem.getClass() == new BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>().getClass());
```

Comment: you have the code, open an IDE and generate the output.

Comment: the problem is that the code does not compile, it shows an error on the Operator class defined in the question

Comment: What's the compiler error then?

Comment: The error is described in the question:
// compile error, collect(OUT) cannot be applied to BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Operator` is generic it cannot apply `collect` on a `BasicPoint`, only `OUT`. You can make your `Collector` abstract:

```
abstract class Operator<OUT extends Point> {
    abstract Collector <OUT> operate(Collector<OUT> collector);
}
```

And a `BasicPointOperator` will then contain the actual implementation which you want:

```
class BasicPointOperator extends Operator<BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>> {

    @Override
    Collector<BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>> operate(Collector<BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>> collector) {
        collector.collect(new BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>(1,2));
        return collector;
    }
}
```

or `PointOperator`, which is a bit more generic

```
class PointOperator extends Operator<Point> {

    @Override
    Collector<Point> operate(Collector<Point> collector) {
        collector.collect(new BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>(1,2));
        return collector;
    }
}
```

Comment: Afaik it _could_ work the way he programmed it in the first place, do you know _why_ it dosent work? I guess the Compiler just ignore the type of `OUT` inside of `Operator`.

Comment: It does not work because `BasicPoint` is not of type `OUT`. They just have a common ancestor `Point`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't put things *in* unless the type parameter is  [contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java). Something like that

```
public Collector<?>  operate(Collector<? super Point> collector) {
    collector.collect(new BasicPoint<Integer, Integer>(1,2));
    collector.collect(new Point());

    return collector;
 }
```