# Can you set a multi-object array and call a method from it?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

To be exact, I'm curious as to whether an Object[] array is capable of storing and accessing other objects' methods. Here's a little example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
//declare an array of *different* objects
private static Object[] function = {new Object1(),
                                    new Object2()}; 
//calls method(getNumber) from Object1()
function[0].getNumber();
```

Since I already found out that you can stack same objects into an array, I want to figure out if its possible to do so with different methods without using ArrayList. Just curious, so if you think there isn't a way to do this just tell me so, thanks :)

Comment: Its probably easier to just call it directly from the object while declaring them separately, right?

Comment: You can do it, with a cast: `(Object1)function[0].myObjectMethod();`

Comment: Why does casting work? Is it because the array itself is only declared as an Object[] type array? Sry bout these qns, i legit just started coding less than half a year ago :P

Comment: Any object array, let's say, MyObject[], is, in it's most basic concept a list of Object with reference to MyObject

Comment: Casting works because this is done at runtime. Not at the compile-time. So, it will case your `Object` into the thing that you are expecting here.

Comment: Noted, i guess I'll go read it up if i need more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, but you should cast before calling a method on the plain object. 
Instead of this:

```
function[0].getNumber();
```

You should do something like this:

```
((MyType) function[0]).getNumber();
```

Comment: didn't know casting could be used like this, Thanks

Comment: Also, please take a look at generics :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501513/2928710

Comment: If the answer hasn't helped don't hesitate to ping :)

Answer (score 0):

If the methods you want to call are the same for all the objects and you control their classes, you should extract the methods to a interface, and let the classes implement it.

This way you could have a `CommonInterface[]` array...

```
public CommonInterface { Number getNumber(); }

CommonInterface[] function = { new Object1(), new Object2() };
function[1].getNumber()
```