# Why can't HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> be converted to HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist

```
HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> test = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

This line gives me the error: `HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> cannot be converted to HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>`

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using Java 7+? Use the diamond operator.. .`Map<Integer, List<Integer> = new HashMap<>()`

Comment: hmm i don't know the version as I am using Leetcode's online Java environment.

Comment: I doubt that it's stuck in Java 6

Answer (score 2):

The underlying `HashMap` would be restricted to `ArrayList`s, but the reference would allow you to add any kind of list. What if you tried to add a `LinkedList` to the `HashMap`?

Probably, you just need to make a `HashMap` of `List`:

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> test = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
```

Or if you really want the restriction that it only contain `ArrayList`s:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> test = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Note that this kind of issue is called covariance and contravariance.

See Also:

- [Demonstrate covariance and contravariance in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java)
- [Covariance, Invariance and Contravariance explained in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english)

This link is about C# instead of Java, but is one of the best explanations of the concept I'm aware of. It won't apply in the same way to Java as it does to C#, but it should be a useful read nevertheless:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because it is "unsafe", and the reason it is unsafe is because you would be hold two reference to the same list with this two types:

```
HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> a;
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> b;
```

So if you are presented with prospective value typed `LinkedList<Integer>` it would be ok to add it two `a` but it wouldn't be ok to add it to `b` since a `LinkedList` is not an `ArrayList`. So by creating the `a` reference out of `b` you are creating a back-door to corrupt the content of the map from `b` reference perspective.

For example down the line someone pulling values from `b` that is expecting `ArrayList` will get a `LinkedList` instead causing a casting exception.