# Unable to case Set<Supertype> to Set<Subtype>

Tags: java, generics

I am getting error while casting  **Set < Supertype >** to **Set< Subtype >**

I am getting following error :

> Cannot cast from Set< AppUserRole > to Set< AppUserRoleEntity >

```
interface AppUserRole {
    void m1();
}

class AppUserRoleEntity implements AppUserRole {

    @Override
    public void m1() {

    }

}

interface AppUser {

    void m2(Set<AppUserRole> abc);
}

class AppUserEntity implements AppUser {

    Set<AppUserRoleEntity> role;

    @Override
    public void m2(Set<AppUserRole> abc) {
        this.role = (Set<AppUserRoleEntity>) abc;// Compilation fails here

    }

}
```

---

After reading PECS I have modified my code like below

```
    Set< ? super AppUserRoleEntity> role;
```

But not on getter method of same class I am getting warning

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Set< capture#2-of ? super
>   AppUserRoleEntity > to Set

```
@Override
    public Set<AppUserRole> getAppUserRoles() {
        return (Set<AppUserRole>) appUserRoles;
    }
```

Can some one tell me how to fix this problem ? Please help

Comment: You need co/contravariance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java and then it will work one way (either co or contravariance)

Comment: "Can some one tell me how to fix this problem ?" -> Yes, deploy [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). TL;DR: generics are not covariant.

Comment: @azurefrog relevant, but it's the other way round: OP is asking why a list of animals can't be cast to a list of dogs. And of course, the answer is that a list of animals might contain cats.

Comment: derp, pre-coffee reading comprehension fail :/

Comment: @AndyTurner-- If you can please help

Comment: @PrzmyslawMoskal same comment I made above to azurefrog. OP is asking about the reverse case.

Comment: @AndyTurner not really, is the same case. OP is trying to cast a `List<Animal>` into a `List<Dog>`. Even if he finds a way so that doesn't fail at compilation, it will fail in runtime when the `List<Animal>` contains something that is not a dog. Like a cat. Or a whale.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this cast in the first place? Why can't the `role` set just be `Set<AppUserRole>`? In your edit, you even appear to be returning the set as a `Set<AppUserRole>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I deleted comment in which there was an information about that I suspect this question as duplicate. It seems that it was not the correct way of releasing the flag that I submitted, because now I have information that my flag was helpful although I reconsidered submitting it. Anyway, thank you for offering your point of view, I actually agree with your opinion now.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to declare the generic type in the interface:

```
interface AppUserRole {
    void m1();
}

class AppUserRoleEntity implements AppUserRole {

    @Override
    public void m1() {

    }

}

interface AppUser<R extends AppUserRole> {

    void m2(Set<R> abc);
}

class AppUserEntity implements AppUser<AppUserRoleEntity> {

    Set<AppUserRoleEntity> role;

    @Override
    public void m2(Set<AppUserRoleEntity> abc) {
        this.role = abc;// No cast needed

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can erase type and do a unchecked cast for your type, as below:

```
@Override
public void m2(Set<AppUserRole> abc) {
    this.role = (Set<AppUserRoleEntity>) (Set<?>) abc;
}
```

Also if Set is typed as accepting a capture of extends AppUser you can do the cast without erasure.

```
@Override
public void m2(Set<? extends AppUserRole> abc) {
    this.role = (Set<AppUserRoleEntity>) abc;
}
```

That is just a unsafe cast. If you pass a item type that is not AppUserRoleEntity the program will throw ClassCastException.

Besides, the best solution is to use the interface and not the implementing type.

Comment: which will fail horribly at runtime when `abc` contains other implementations than `AppUserRoleEntity`

Comment: An explicit cast will also fails

Comment: ... which is why we have [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)