# Can't use parent as variable types and yet receive child types

Tags: java, retrofit2

Hi I am working with `java 8`. Below is the case:

I have an empty interface `AsyncResponse` like below:

```
package com.personal.carrot.core.models;

public interface AsyncResponse {
}
```

And I have a model `APIResponse`

```
package com.personal.carrot.core.models;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class APIResponse implements AsyncResponse {

    @JsonProperty("numberOfFeatures")
    public Long numberOfFeatures;

}
```

And finally I have a service using `Retrofit2` to make my API response:

```
public interface APIRepository {
    @POST("MYURL")
    Call<APIResponse> resolveCounts(@Body HashMap<String, String> body);
}
```

Now when I call the APIRepository like below:

```
Call<AsyncResponse> request = repository.resolveCounts(payload);
```

I get an error:

> java: incompatible types: retrofit2.Call (com.personal.carrot.core.models.APIResponse) cannot be converted to retrofit2.Call(com.personal.carrot.core.models.AsyncResponse)

Comment: @ernest_k No there is a single instance JVM & this is a compile time error.

Comment: Does it work if you use `Call<? extends AsyncResponse>`?

Comment: See [the oracle generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html): "Box<Integer> and Box<Double> are not subtypes of Box<Number>" - if `resolveCounts` returns an `Call<APIResponse>`, you cannot assign that to an `Call<AsyncResponse>`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because you cannot assign a `Call<APIResponse>` to a `Call<AsyncResponse>`. Generic types are invariant.

You probably have to use `APIResponse` as type argument for your variable:

```
Call<APIResponse> request = repository.resolveCounts(payload);
```

That is not because you can't design your code to use the interface `AsyncResponse`, but because (I'm presuming here) the framework uses the return type to process content-type-related bindings.

Answer (score 0):

**Why It Doesn't Work**

Contrary to the common understanding about polymorphism (which is what you are trying to accomplish here), it doesn't apply to generics.

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList();
List<Object> objectList = strList;
```

The above example will produce a compilation error.

This is because IF we allow the second line to succeed, there may be a situation where subsequently `objectList` gets assigned a list of another type (e.g. `List<Integer>`). `strList` will now be 'corrupted' because `objectList` holds the same reference as `strList`.

As such, we need to return the exact same type as what that list is explicitly declaring to hold, and not either a sub-class or super-class of `AsyncResponse`.

**Potential Solutions**

Depending on what you are trying to achieve here, a potential solution would be:

```
Call<APIResponse> request = repository.resolveCounts(payload);
```

or (and I haven't tried this yet):

```
Call<? extends ASyncResponse> request = repository.resolveCounts(payload);
```