# Java : generics and lambda expression

Tags: java, generics, lambda

This looks like very basic but I fail to understand why my code doesn't compile.

I have a `class Person` with a `String name` attribute and a `getName()` getter.

I create an `Employee class extends Person`

I have this method :

```
public Predicate<? extends Person> startsA() {
        return p -> p.getName().startsWith("A");
}
```

So I want this method to work with all subclasses of `Person`

But this code doesn't compile :

```
startsA().test(new Employee());
startsA().test(new Person());
```

I don't understand why

Comment: Just change `Predicate<? extends Person>` to `Predicate<Person>`.

Comment: Or if you want to allow the method to return `Predicate<Employee>`, use `public <P extends Person> Predicate<P>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Give examples of functions which demonstrate covariance and contravariance in the cases of both overloading and overriding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/give-examples-of-functions-which-demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-th)

Comment: ok thanks. Isn't <? extends Person> and <P extends Person> <P> the same thing ?

Comment: No, they are not the same thing.  Every Predicate has a specific, non-wildcard type.  `Predicate<? extends Person>` means “this Predicate’s specific type is either Person or some class that inherits Person, but I don’t know what that specific type is.”  When you try to call test(new Person()), it is not type-safe, because the *specific type* of the Predicate might be Employee, or Customer, or OlympicAthlete.  `? extends Person` means the compiler doesn’t know which specific type the Predicate requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are one meta level removed. You need to walk a mile in the shoes of the compiler to understand them.

The mistake I often see with generics, and the one you seem to make, is that you think `Predicate<? extends Person>` means 'this is a predicate that can test any person. An Employee, a Customer - doesn't matter, hence, 'whatever extends Person' right.

**But that is not what that means**.

After all, imagine it meant that. What is `Predicate<Person>` then? A predicate that can test only specifically `new Person()` but not `new Employer()`? Java doesn't work that way - any instance of Employer can be used as a Person so that would be utterly bizarre.

In fact, `Predicate<Person>` means what you want here: A predicate object that can **test any person**.

So what does `Predicate<? extends Person>` mean? This:

A predicate that can test... I don't actually know what it can test. All I know is, whatever it is, it's some type that is either Person or some subtype thereof.

So what point is there to such a thing? Not all that much in this specific case (for predicate). Let's instead think of lists. We have 3 different types that are relevant (remember, Integer and Double both extend Number, and Number extends Object)

- `List<? extends Number>`
- `List<? super Number>`
- `List<Number>`

You can pass a `List<Integer>` object to a method that takes a `List<? extends Number>`. You **cannot** pass it to a method that takes a `List<Number>`. Why not - Integer extends Number, right? Ah, but **inside generics**, that's invariant, as in, no, you can't just replace a type with its subtype. After all, I can add a `Double` object to a `List<Number>`. I can add Number objects to my list, a Double object is a Number object, QED.

But, adding a Double object to a `List<Integer>`, that's no good. Hence, a `List<? extends Number>` is required - try it, you **cannot** add things to such a list. For the same reason: `List<? extends Number>` does not mean: "A list that can hold numbers - any numbers". Quite the opposite. It means: "A list that can hold.. I do not know what it can hold (hence the question mark!) - all I know is, whatever it holds, it's Number. Or any subclass of Number). Given that, `list.get(5)` WILL return an expression of type `Number` (given the few things we know, that is safe), but you can't add anything to it (except for the academic case of a literal `null`, which is all types).

For `Predicate` in particular, `Predicate<? extends>` is completely useless, that shouldn't ever show up in any case. `Predicate<? super X>` can be quite convenient. After all, that means: "A predicate that can test.. well I do not know what it can test. What I do know, is that it is either X, or some **super** type of X". Given that information, `.test(instanceOfX)` is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. You perfectly understood what I failed to understand when it comes to generics

Comment: It's useful to mention the PECS (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`) rule. Since `Predicate` is solely a consumer of its type parameter, it can always be used with `super` wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code doesn't compile is because you have defined the `startsA()` method to return a Predicate of a wildcard type that extends Person.
The wildcard type represents an unknown subtype of Person,

Change `startsA()` method to return a `Predicate<Person>` instead of using a wildcard type:

```
public Predicate<Person> startsA() {
    return p -> p.getName().startsWith("A");
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer: any `Employee` is a `Person`, but any `Employee` cannot be a subtype of an unknown subclass of `Person` (which `? extends Person` implies). Same holds for any subclass of `Person` (ie `Employee` is just an example here).